# DSolve "Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first \ argument "

Tags: differential-equations

I am getting the error:

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first
>   argument

when I try to evaluate the cell.

```
DSolve[{24 X1''[t] + 64 X1[t] - 32 x2[t] == 0, 
        16 X2''[t] - 32 X1[t] + 64 X2[t] - 32 X3[t] == 0, 
         8 X3''[t] - 32 X2[t] + 32 X3[t] == 0,
         X1[0] == 0, X2[0] == 0, X3[0] == 20, 
         X1'[0] == 20, X2'[0] == 0, X3'[0] == 0}, {X1[t], X2[t], X3[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Run ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` and try again.

Comment: @J.M. Does it spit anything out on your machine?

Comment: Do we have a canonical answer for this type of error somewhere on the site?  It seems to come up a lot, and it'd be helpful to be able to mark such questions as duplicates and point the askers towards the already-answered question.

Comment: @michael writing "try restarting mma" or similar is not more cumbersome than linking another post. And it usually needs confirmation from the OP before closing

Comment: @Dr. bel, I'm not at a machine today; just took a quick stab based on my *gedanken* version. ;)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert [(40314)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/121)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some lingering definition that is spoiling the evaluation. Besides, you wrote a lowercase `x2` on the first line. The following returns quite fast
and fix both problems

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
DSolve[{
  24 X1''[t] + 64 X1[t] - 32 X2[t] == 0,
  16 X2''[t] - 32 X1[t] + 64 X2[t] - 32 X3[t] == 0,
  8 X3''[t] - 32 X2[t] + 32 X3[t] == 0,
  X1[0] == 0, X2[0] == 0, X3[0] == 20, X1'[0] == 20, X2'[0] == 0, 
  X3'[0] == 0}, {X1[t], X2[t], X3[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Nevertheless the resulting expression is quite long