# Clearing Problem with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Consider:

[image]

This is a classic mistake (using a single equal sign) that has been discussed on Mathematica Stack Exchange before. I know that Clear[Derivative] will cure the problem. However, consider the following.

[image]

?f' does not reveal anything in the global workspace. Neither does ?f'[x]. Yet f'[x]=. clears the problem, so I believe something is stored in f'[x] but why can't I see it with the question mark process. Any way to see it?

Comment: Since the value is mistakenly assigned to `Derivative`, does `?Derivative` contain that information?

Comment: @MarcoB After entering `Clear[f, x]` and `DSolve[{f'[x]=8x^3+12x+3,f[1]==6]},f[x],x]`, entering ?Derivative just brings up instructions for the Derivative command, not the content of f'[x].

Comment: Related: [Error entering equation in DSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve), which is your old question :) Halirutan's answer there answers this question, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for pointing out the old question. Been a while. I have trouble searching through all the old questions I've asked. How do you find them so quickly? And, thanks for all the tremendous help you've given me over the years.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, it turns out that you can obtain those definitions using `SubValues`:

```
Clear[f, x]
f'[x] = 3 x

SubValues[Derivative]

(* Out: {HoldPattern[Derivative[1][f][x]] :> 3 x} *)
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/27951), `SubValues` is used for definitions of the following type:

```
d[e][f] = something;
```

As you know, `f'[x]` is really interpreted as `Derivative[1][f][x]`, so setting `f'[x] = something` generates a `SubValue` for `Derivative`.

Adapting a phrase from the linked answer: "This defines neither an `OwnValue` nor a `DownValue` for `Derivative`, since it does not really define the value for the atomic object `Derivative` itself, but for `Derivative[1][f]`, which is a composite."