# Trying to solve ODE. Need help with error messages

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

With this code I get an error-message:

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument.

Apparently `y'[0] == v0` gives `True`. The code does work if I put `y'[1] == v0`.

Question: what is happening here and why and how can I avoid this?

```
a = 1
b = 0.2
c = 4
y0 = 8.5
v0 = 0
DSolve[{a y''[t] + b y'[t] + c y[t] == 0, y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0}, y[t], t]
```

By the way, if I use `DSolveValue`, then I get the same results, though with a different error-message:

> Equation or list of equations expected in the first argument.

Comment: It works fine for me. Just restart mma and run this code again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error entering equation in DSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I get when I try your equation:

```
a = 1; b = 0.2; c = 4; y0 = 8.5; v0 = 0;

DSolve[{a y''[t] + b y'[t] + c y[t] == 0, y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0}, y[t], t]

(* {{y[t] -> 8.5 E^(-0.1 t) (1. Cos[1.9975 t] + 0.0500626 Sin[1.9975 t])}} *)
```

You may need to restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Hmmm, that indeed worked! But... why?

Comment: @ImreVégh. It could be one of a variety of reasons. You may have previously stored a value in `y'[0]`, so when you used `y'[0] == v0` you got the result `True`.

Comment: @ImreVégh If RunnyKine is right, see the answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve) for further explanation.