# NDSolve beginner

Tags: differential-equations

I just started to use Mathematica. I don't manage to use NDSolve. For example, when I write

```
 s2 = NDSolve[{y[x]^2 = x, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}] 
    Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s2], {x, 1, 2}]
```

It doesn't plot curve on the graph... May it be because of the version ? I'm using 10.3

Thanks

---

Thx !

Actually, the equation I'm trying to solve is :

```
pde = 1/x^2*D[x^2*f[x], x] + 
f[x]*((-2 + 12*f[x]^2)*1/x^2*D[x^2*f[x], x] - 
  1/x^2*D[x^2*D[1/x^2*D[x^2*f[x], x], x], x]) == 0

sol = NDSolve[{pde, f'[0] == 0, f''[1] == 0, f[0] ==1}, 
f, {x, -5, 5}]
```

But apparently, the last boundary condition is not good since I get in the answer 
        "... True,True,f[0] == 1..."
 Do you have an idea how I can choose or make the programm choose a better condition ?
 If I don't write it, it doesn't plot anyting neither...

Comment: You have several mistakes: First `y[x]^2 = x` should be `y[x]^2 == x`. Secondly, you are trying to solve a ODE but actually you have not included a derivative of the function at all!

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve

Comment: you should not lump together multiple questions. You see now the first one is answered and the issue with the second one is unrelated.  The "True", etc output indicates something has some old definition. Restart your kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Let'see a correct usage:

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] + y[x]^2 == x, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}] (*assigne the solution, in the form of interpolating function, to the variable s*)

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All] (*plot the function y[x]*)
```

As I have already mentioned there are several mistakes in your code: First y[x]^2 = x should be y[x]^2 == x. Secondly, you are trying to solve a ODE but actually you forgot to include a derivative of the function.