# Manipulate plot of a system of PDEs with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, physics

Modeling 1D diffusion of an enzyme, e, through a sphere with substrate, s, I arrive at the below equations:
[image: Kappa is a constant and D_r is the Diffusivity of the enzyme. The first "e" is actually meant to be exp]

I then pass these equations to NDSolve, Evaluate at a range of r and t and Plot and Manipulate as follows.

```
 Manipulate[
    sol2 = NDSolve[{
    D[sub[rad, tim], tim] == -(sub[rad, tim]) (en[rad, tim]),
    D[en[rad, tim], 
      tim] == (1/(k2/(k2 + k1r)))*(D0/((length^2) e0*k1f))*
      D[(Exp[beta (1 - sub[rad, tim])] D[en[rad, tim], rad]), rad],
    (*initial conditions*)
    sub[rad, 0] == s0, en[rad, 0] == 0,
    (*boundary conditions*)
    en[0, tim] == 1, sub[1, tim] == 1
    }, {sub, en}, {rad, 0, r0}, {tim, 0, 10}];
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[{sub[rad, tim], en[rad, tim]} /. sol2, {tim, 1, 10}]], {rad, 
   0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Front Position", "Concentration"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"substrate", "enzyme"}],
 {{s0, 1}, 1, 10, 1},
 {{k2, .5}, 0.1, 1},
 {{k1r, 0.5}, 0.1, 1},
 {{k1f, 1}, 1, 10, 1},
 {{r0, 1}, 0, 1},
 {{e0, 1}, 0.1, 1},
 {{D0, .001}, 0.001, 1},
 {{length, 1}, 1, 10},
 {{beta, 1}, 0, 6}
 ]
```

Comment: It looks like `Toolbox` is not compatible with version 12.

Comment: The code contains many typos: 1) use == instead of = in (*boundary conditions*); 2) use D[,r] instead of $\nabla _r$ 3) replace 'c[r,t]` by `(s[r, t]*e[r, t])/kappa`; 4) to avoid division by 0 exclude `e[r,0]== 0`; 5) don't use `Toolbox`6) define constants `kappa`, $D_r$ ;7) add boundary conditions.

Comment: Please include the error message name.

Comment: The first error @AlexTrounev points out sounds like the cause of the `NDSolve` error.  Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Second::shdw: Symbol Second appears in multiple contexts {AutomaticUnits`,Prototypes`}; definitions in context AutomaticUnits` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
Fifth::shdw: Symbol Fifth appears in multiple contexts {AutomaticUnits`,Prototypes`}; definitions in context AutomaticUnits` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
Molecule::shdw: Symbol Molecule appears in multiple contexts {AutomaticUnits`,System`}; definitions in context AutomaticUnits` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.`

Comment: Thank you Alex and Michael! I applied your corrections and it works almost perfectly. I've updated the post with the stand alone code without toolbox or any externally defined constants. The only warningI have left is "boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent"