# Confused by result of NDSolve for Second-Order nonlinear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, warning-messages, nonlinear

It is impossible to solve numerically a nonlinear second-order equation, although the initial conditions are given.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {α = 0.15, h = 1, ω = 2 Pi 0.25, T = 1};

    extr = -(x[t] - 1)^2;
    
    func = extr + (D[
           x[t] - α Sin[ω t] + 
            D[x[t] - α Sin[ω t], t]/T, t] - 0)^2;
    
    sys1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
         func α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t], 
        x[0] == 2, x'[0] == -2}, x, {t, 0, 500}];

NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument {(x^′)[t]==0.235619 Cos[1.5708 t]+0.15 Sin[1.5708 t] (-Plus[<<2>>]^2+(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>])^2),x[0]==2,False}.
```

Comment: You need `Clear[Derivative]`. This isn't the only problem, though.

Comment: One thing I can spot is, the ODE and the i.c. are inconsistent. Just try: `{x'[t] == func \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t] + D[\[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t], t], x[0] == 2, 
 x'[0] == -2}/.t->0`. If they should not, there's something wrong with your equation, please double check it.

Comment: `NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {x[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.`

Comment: I don't mean that you should feed the sample into `NDSolve`. Please execute it separately and observe the output, then you should understand what I mean.

Comment: `{Derivative[1][x][0] == 0.235619, x[0] == 2, Derivative[1][x][0] == -2}`

Comment: Once again, please observe the output.

Comment: As mentioned above, I think this indicates something is wrong with the equation itself, and I'm afraid only someone who has a good understanding to the underlying model (in other words, you) can fix this.

Comment: @xzczd

Please, see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve

Comment: To solve your IVP, you need to resolve the singularity at `t == 0`.

Comment: There are similar singularities when `t` is an even integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we take care of the singularity at `t == 0` and let `"StiffnessSwitching"` + a high working precision slide past the rest of them, which occur whenever `t` is equal to an even integer.

Set up:

```
Block[{α = 15/100, h = 1, ω = 2 Pi /4, T = 1},
 extr = -(x[t] - 1)^2;
 func = extr + (D[
       x[t] - α Sin[ω t] + 
        D[x[t] - α Sin[ω t], t]/T, t] - 0)^2;
 
 ode = {x'[t] == 
    func α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t]};
 ics = {x[0] == 2, x'[0] == -2};
 ]
```

Form a solution of the form $x(t) = u(t) + \Delta x(t)$, where $u''(0)$ is finite and $\Delta x''(0)$ is infinite. Then derive the ODE for $u$, integrate, and form the solution for $x$:

```
xpp = Solve[ode, x''[t]];
xpp /. Thread[{x[t], 
     x'[t]} -> ({x[t], x'[t]} /. t -> 0 /. Solve@ics // First)];
% // Simplify;
xpp0 = x''[t] /. %;

dx = (Series[#, {t, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> t > 0] & /@ 
     xpp0) /.
   {HoldPattern[
      SeriesData[t_, t0_, coeff_, min_?Negative, max_, denom_]] :>
     Total@Take[coeff*(t - t0)^(Range[min, max - 1]/denom), -min],
    _SeriesData :> 0};
dx = Integrate[dx, t, t]

{-(4/3) I Sqrt[1 + 80/(3 π)] t^(3/2), 
 4/3 I Sqrt[1 + 80/(3 π)] t^(3/2)}

uodes = MapThread[
    Function[{pp, dx}, 
     x''[t] == pp /. {x -> (u[#] + dx &)}], {x''[t] /. 
      xpp, (dx /. t -> #)}
    ] // Simplify;
upp = First@Solve[#, u''[t]] & /@ uodes;

uppic = MapThread[
  Function[{pp, dx},
   Limit[u''[t] /. pp /. 
     Thread[{u[t], 
        u'[t]} -> ({u[0], u'[0]} /. 
         First@Solve[ics /. x -> (u[#] + dx &)])],
    t -> 0,
    Direction -> "FromAbove"]
   ],
  {upp, dx /. t -> #}]
(* only one branch satisfies IC *)

(* {DirectedInfinity[I], 2 + 40/(3*Pi) + (3*Pi)/40}  *)

obj[t_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, up_?NumericQ] =
  Piecewise[
    {{u''[t] /. Last@upp, t > 0}},
    Last@uppic] /. {u[t] -> u, u'[t] -> up};
uics = Equal @@@ 
   First@Solve[ics /. x -> (Evaluate[u[#] + Last@dx /. t -> #] &)];

usol = NDSolve[{u''[t] == obj[t, u[t], u'[t]], uics},
    u, {t, 0, 100.1},
    InterpolationOrder -> All,
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}},
    MaxSteps -> 100000,
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
      "WarningMessage" -> False}
    , WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 8
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {44.0669, Null}  *)

xsol = {x -> (Evaluate[u[#] + Last@dx /. t -> #] &)} /. usol;
```

Check initial conditions:

```
ics /. xsol

(*  {{True, True}}  *)
```

Visualize:

```
ReImPlot[x[t] /. xsol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Residual error on the original ODE:

```
Plot[ode /. Equal -> Subtract /. xsol // RealExponent // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment: The initial conditions aren't consistent!

The ode at `t==0`  evaluates to

```
x'[t] == func \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t] + D[\[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t], t] /. t -> 0  
(*Derivative[1][x][0] == 0.235619*)
```

which differs from your  second initial condition `x'[0]==2`!

Be aware, that your ode switches between first and second order. That seems to be hard to handle by  `NDSolve`

Some of the error messages `NDSolve` might be bypassed if you use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`:

```
X = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] ==func \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t] + D[\[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t], t],x[0] == 2, x'[0] == -2}, x, {t, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```