# NDSolve does not work at all. It always shows me the "Equation or list of equations..." error, even though I've cleared ALL cache and data

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

Literally a one line code:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] + 3, x[0]==3, x'[0]==3}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

It shows me the error, that:

> NDSolve : Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True,x[0]==3,False}.

Why does Mathematica interpret my equation as "true", and my second initial condition as "false"?

I am really desperate, I can't find a solution to that at all anywhere on the internet. Even using "ClearAll["Global`*"]" doesn't do ANYTHING

Comment: I start Mathematica fresh, so there is nothing in the cache, and I enter exactly `sol=x[t]/.NDSolve[{x'[t]==x[t]+3,x[0]==3},x[t],{t,0,10}][[1]];
Plot[sol,{t,0,10}]` and I get a plot of your result. Try EXACTLY those steps and see what you get. I didn't give it two conditions because a first order ODE expects one condition. Does this work for you?

Comment: You probably did at some point what is described in the [linked Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve?noredirect=1&lq=1), namely used `=` instead of `==` in a couple of places. If so, it can be fixed as shown in a couple of the answers.  Note that it is explained there why ``ClearAll["Global`*"]` does not fix this problem.