# Unable to solve a couple complex valued differential equation usingNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to use the `NDSolve` to deal with the following odes

```
sol = NDSolve[{a'[
     t] == -I/2 (a[t] + 0.1 b[t] (Cos[10 t] + I*Sin[10 t])), 
   b'[t] == -I/2 (-b[t] + 0.1 a[t] (Cos[10 t] - I*Sin[10 t])), 
   a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 10 Pi}]
```

But I return with a message that

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument
```

I wonder if it is because the ode is unsolvable or I just didn't use the right method. Any help would be appreciated. Best.

Comment: Try with clean kernel. Also, do not write everything in one big command. makes it hard to maintain. try this `ClearAll[a,b,t];
ode1=a'[t]==-I/2 (a[t]+0.1 b[t] (Cos[10 t]+I*Sin[10 t]));
ode2=b'[t]==-I/2 (-b[t]+0.1 a[t] (Cos[10 t]-I*Sin[10 t]));
ic={a[0]==1,b[0]==0};` and now do `sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 10 Pi}]`  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abbtk.png)  whenever you get such error, better to start with clean kernel.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve for a discussion.

Comment: In addition to what @Nasser said, you probably need to clear `Derivative`: `Clear[a, b, t, Derivative];` -- As in the linked Q&A, you probably accidentally wrote single `=` instead of a `==` and then fixed that. But the mistake defined a value for `Derivative` that needs clearing.

Comment: Work fine here.  `{ReImPlot[a[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 2 π}],
 ReImPlot[b[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 2 π}]}`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much. It saves the problem!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact constants in the equations and use [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) and [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
eqns = {a'[t] == -I/2 (a[t] + 1/10 b[t] (Cos[10 t] + I*Sin[10 t])), 
     b'[t] == -I/2 (-b[t] + 1/10 a[t] (Cos[10 t] - I*Sin[10 t])), a[0] == 1, 
     b[0] == 0} // TrigToExp // Simplify;
```

The exact solutions are then

```
sol = DSolve[eqns, {a, b}, t][[1]]

(* {a -> Function[{t}, (1/
   24202)(12101 E^(I (5 - Sqrt[12101]/20) t) + 
     110 Sqrt[12101] E^(I (5 - Sqrt[12101]/20) t) + 
     12101 E^(I (5 + Sqrt[12101]/20) t) - 
     110 Sqrt[12101] E^(I (5 + Sqrt[12101]/20) t))], 
 b -> Function[{t}, (
   E^(-10 I t) (E^(I (5 - Sqrt[12101]/20) t) - E^(
      I (5 + Sqrt[12101]/20) t)))/(2 Sqrt[12101])]} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

The simplified solutions are

```
funcs = {a[t], b[t]} /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {E^(5 I t) Cos[(Sqrt[12101] t)/20] - (
  110 I E^(5 I t) Sin[(Sqrt[12101] t)/20])/Sqrt[12101], -((
  I E^(-5 I t) Sin[(Sqrt[12101] t)/20])/Sqrt[12101])} *)
```