# Solving third order DE from fluid dynamics

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, boundary-condition-at-infinity, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to use `DSolve` to solve a differential equation from *G. Batchelor: An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics*, eq. 5.12.4:

> [...] equation now reduces to
> $$\boxed{f'''+2ff''+2f'^2=0.} \tag{5.12.4}$$
> The test of the hypothesis lies in being able to find a solution of this equation which satisfies
> $$ f'(\eta) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad \eta\to\pm \infty,$$
> and the symmetry condition $f'(\eta) = f'(-\eta)$. Such a solution is
> $$f(\eta) = \alpha \tanh \left(\alpha \eta\right), \tag{5.12.6}$$
> where $\alpha$ is a constant [...]

However, the result I get in *Mathematica* is a complicated function containing [`AiryAi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryAi.html) and [`AiryBi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryBi.html):

```
DSolve[y'''[x] + 2 y''[x] y[x] + 2 y'[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x] 
(* {{y[x] -> -((
    AiryBiPrime[(x C[1] - C[2])/C[1]^(2/3)] C[1]^(1/3) + 
     AiryAiPrime[(x C[1] - C[2])/C[1]^(2/3)] C[1]^(1/3) C[
      3])/(-AiryBi[(x C[1] - C[2])/C[1]^(2/3)] - 
            AiryAi[(x C[1] - C[2])/C[1]^(2/3)] C[3]))}} *)
```

How can I match the result from Mathematica with the one provided in the textbook?

Comment: What do you mean by _unclear, erratic_ output? `DSolve` returns a [nice result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt2Ah.png) with [`AiryAi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryAi.html) and [`AiryBi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AiryBi.html).

Comment: I have significantly edited your question – I hope it captures the essential question you are after.

Comment: Coefficient::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable. >>

Comment: if you are new to Mathematica, you should start from the beginning. For example, read the [introduction](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/). It seems that you have previously defined `y`. Use `Clear[x, y]` before executing `DSolve` to clear their values. As for the font, you have the magnification option in the bottom-right corner of the window.

Comment: Please pay attention: What is the initial condition? Is it $y''(0)=0$, as you've written in the question, or $y'(0)=0$, as you are using now in the code?

Comment: Sorry it is 2nd derivative zero at x=-0 because 1st derivative is symmetric

Comment: For the deqn error mentioned in the comments, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve

Comment: Ok v9 gives Airy result with 3 constants whereas only 1 in GKB so 2 are probably zero here. How ask it what y"[0] is or y'[Infinity]?

Comment: Nasser y"(0)=0 condition is a consequence of symmetry of y' that GKB used. Thought would be easier for Mathematica DSolve[{(y'''[x] + 2*y''[x]*y[x] + 2 y'[x]^2 == 0), (y''[0] == 0), (y'[Infinity] == 0)}, y[x], x] returns                                                        
 {{y[x] -> (
   0 AiryBiPrime[ComplexInfinity] + 
    0 AiryAiPrime[ComplexInfinity] C[3])/(
   AiryBi[ComplexInfinity] + AiryAi[ComplexInfinity] C[3])}}DSolve::bvlim: For some branches of the general solution, unable to compute the limit at the given points. Some of the solutions may be lost. >>

Comment: DSolve::bvsing: Unable to resolve some of the arbitrary constants in the general solution using the given boundary conditions. It is possible that some of the conditions have been specified at a singular point for the equation. No  nothing singular here

Comment: -((a AiryBiPrime[a x])/AiryBi[a x]) where a=cube root C[1] is that the same as aTanh[xa] ? as won't Simplify to it

Comment: Nasser, ok use GKB DSolve[{(y'''[x] + 2*y''[x]*y[x] + 2 y'[x]^2 == 0), (y'[x] == 
    y'[-x]), (y'[Infinity] == 0)}, y[x], x]DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {2 (y^\[Prime])[x]^2+2 y[x] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]+(y^(3))[x]==0,(y^\[Prime])[x]==(y^\[Prime])[-x]} should literally match the independent variables. >>

Comment: This is hard to show in Mathematica, I tried but nothing worked. May be contact the author and ask them how they came up with this solution or may be someone will have an idea. Try asking in the math forum also.

Comment: Regrettably GK Batchelor FRS has been dead for at least 20 years. Thank you Nasser for trying. I was going to change/perturb GKB's p and q if I had any confidence about Mathematica solving the perturbed eqn

Answer (score 8):

One can observe that the original equation can be simply integrated twice w.r.t. $x$, this yields:    $$y'(x)+y(x)^2-c_2\; x+c_1=0 $$ We could choose arbitrarily signs of constants, now solving it with `DSolve` without any conditions yields the original result as solving original equation. Now, take a closer look at     $\quad y'(x)+y(x)^2-c_2\; x+c_1=0$. Condition that $y'(x)$ tends to zero when $x \to \infty$ implies that $c_2$ must be zero assuming that solution $y(x)$ is finite at infinity, which is a natural assumption for  physically reliable solutions in fluid dynamics. Now rewriting $c_1=-A^2$ we find that

```
DSolveValue[{y'[x] + y[x]^2 - A^2 == 0}, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> A Tanh[A (x + C[1])]
> ```

Now with $\;y''(0)=0$ we find that `C[1]` must be zero

```
Reduce[ D[A Tanh[A (x + c)], {x, 2}] == 0 /. x :> 0, c, Reals]
```

> ```
>  (A != 0 && c == 0) || A == 0
> ```

For $\;A=0$ the solution is trivial and so $c=0$.
Finally we find that $$y(x)=A \tanh(Ax)$$

Concluding we should remark that the special solution $A \tanh(Ax)$ cannot be obtained directly from the general solution found with `DSolve` without any condition on solutions (this is not surprising for nonlinear differential equations), since plugging appropriate constants to the general solution yields a singular expression

```
DSolveValue[ y'[x] + y[x]^2 - c1 x - A^2 == 0, y[x], x] /. c1 :> 0 // 
Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Nevertheless we can choose appropriately parameters such that the general solution and the special solution are quite close at least locally.
Defining a general solution:

```
ygs[x_, A_, d1_, d2_] := -((
  d1^(1/3) d2 AiryAiPrime[(A^2 + d1 x)/d1^(2/3)] + 
  d1^(1/3) AiryBiPrime[(A^2 + d1 x)/d1^(2/3)])/(-d2 AiryAi[(
    A^2 + d1 x)/d1^(2/3)] - AiryBi[(A^2 + d1 x)/d1^(2/3)]))
```

We would be interested with an `Asymptotic` approach on `ygs` when `d1` tends to `zero` however without playing with complicated expressions, let's demonstrate an example.

```
With[{ A = 0.169, c1 = 0.003, c2 = 14}, 
  Plot[{A Tanh[A x], ygs[x, A, c1, c2]}, {x, -12, 12}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Immediate Thank you very much Artes for all this work, a veritable tour de force. NowI must study all this thought closely and see whether it will generalise for the way I was thinking of generalising the original problem.

Comment: Elegant math solution unfortunately not generalizable for different GKB p and q. Need to think about perturbations to p and q.. Unfortunately I still don't understand much of the Mathematica you did, but I can't  expect it to solve generalised problem when didn't solve this one, (even when reformulatedf). Thanks again

Comment: @simon I'm glad I could help. A natural aim of generalizing special solutions in fluid dynamics should be confronted with the fact that in general solutions are very unstable especially for ideal fluids. The Euler equations are considered to be the most unstable equations in physics. Nonetheless they are really important.

Comment: Need a jet solution without a Force at origin, (not so worried if mass flux reappears). so need integral u*u dy to be slight positive power of x which means increasing p above 1/3 and decreasing q below the 2/3 here. Unfortunately Nasser didn't photo that lead in text above the eqn. This is all in aid of a 2D solution for vexed problem of actuator line (Vawt)  vortex wake as simpler version of 3D actuator disc (Hawt) wake,.

Comment: As wrote before suspect -((a AiryBiPrime[a x])/AiryBi[a x]) where a=cube root C[1] ,C[2]=C[3]=0 is  the same as aTanh[xa] ? so that the Tanh solution is within the realm of the general Airy but don't know how to prove in Mathematica and have no previous experience of Airy or its varieties.

Comment: @simon No, these expressions are not equal, see e.g. `With[{A = 9/10}, 
 Plot[{A Tanh[A x], (A AiryBiPrime[A x])/ AiryBi[A x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]]`. They can be equal around $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Funny how midsection of Airy looks like x=aTanh(ay)

Comment: Artes, Didn't you mean c1=-A*A actually to fit with tanh2+sech2=1 identity

Comment: I just finished writing all this up as an appendix and could send you as a docx or pdf. Its down to one page now.. I would like to put your post as a reference in my paper. You were right there are difficulties lurking everywhere. SimonPFarthing@gmail.com