# Using ForAll in Maximize to define a bunch of conditions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to do something very straight forward. The following maximization works:

```
Maximize[{
    (Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2]), 
    Sum[Subscript[a, x], {x, 1, 2}] == 1 , 
    0 <= Subscript[a, 1] <= 1, 
    0 <= Subscript[a, 2] <= 1}, 
  {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}]
```

> ```
> {1, {Subscript[a, 1] -> 1, Subscript[a, 2] -> 0}}
> ```

Now I'd like to do something identical, but using `ForAll`. I need to do this because the real optimization I'm trying to do will have 144 variables, most easily defined by subscripts.

Why doesn't the following work?

```
Maximize[{
    Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, 2], 
    Sum[Subscript[a, x], {x, 1, 2}] == 1 , 
    Resolve[ForAll[x, x ∈ Integers && 1 <= x < 2, Subscript[a, x] >= 0]]}, 
  {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}]
```

> ```
> Maximize[{
>     Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, 2], 
>     Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] == 1, 
>     ForAll[{x}, x ∈ Integers && 1 <= x < 2, Subscript[a, x] >= 0]}, 
>   {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}]
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: In answer to your P.S., you cannot display `Subscript` variables in Mathematica format on StackExchange.  This is, however, one of the lesser reasons for not using `Subscript`.

Comment: Subscript will not do what you want it to.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373 for more details and some workarounds.  The *very* short version is `Subscript[a,1]=3` assigns a value to the function Subscript (when evaluated at (a,1)), it does not create a symbol $a_1$.

Comment: Perhaps the conditions could be constructed, for example: `n = 144;
vars = Array[a, n];
obj = Sum[a[k], {k, n}];
cons = Table[0 <= a[k] <= 1, {k, n}];
Maximize[Join[{obj}, cons], vars]`