# Subscript vs. Brackets

Tags: symbolic, subscript

I'm used to using `Ctr+_` to create indexes for variables (which evaluates to something like `Subscript[a,i,j]`), but on this site I often see people giving answers with the form `a[i,j]`. I find the compact 'visual' subscript to be easy to read and I'm always a little startled when I read the brackets. I'm guessing the bracket form is used on this site because of the Markdown code format.

Is there a strength/weakness to either?

Comment: Please refer to the following post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395

Comment: See [`Clear` does not work on subscripted symbols](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/5) for an example of how this can trip you up.

Comment: Thanks. I wish those, and the two pages referenced in 2) of the [Basic syntax issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/12386) answer had showed up in my searches, but I was getting nothing. I'm guessing `a=Table[a[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]` is still a no-no? I know to avoid naming things with capital letters, but 'capital matrices and lowercase entries' is a hard habit to change, and using different letter for the entries and the matrix makes it hard to connect them mentally.

Comment: Look at [Format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html), e.g., `Format[a[i_, j_]] := Subscript[a, i, j]`