# Having issue for solving a system with seven equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system with seven equations and three constrains. I tried to solve them using `NSolve`, but it takes forever without getting any result. Also, I tried it without any constraints, but again no luck.

I will appreciate if somebody can help me out.

```
eqns = {Subscript[c, 2] + 
      Subscript[a, 2] Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844] == 5 && 
    3000 Subscript[c, 3] == 7 && 
    5 (127 - 10 d)^2 Subscript[a, 3] + 
      2 (-7 + (6350 - 500 d) Subscript[b, 3] + 
         1000 Subscript[c, 3]) == 0 && 
    10627269662 Subscript[b, 3] == 
     2478589 Subscript[a, 2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844] && 
    6400000 Subscript[a, 3] == 
     373 Subscript[a, 2]
       Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844] && (127/10 - d) Subscript[a, 3] + 
      Subscript[b, 3] == (5 (1 + (2457 k)/800))/8128 && 
    20048005 (6129 + 254 d (-5 + Subscript[c, 2])) + 
      20377872376 Subscript[a, 2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844] == 0 && 
    0 <= d <= 127/10 && 0 < k < 1};

qq = NSolve[
   eqns, {Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
    Subscript[b, 3], Subscript[c, 3], d, k}, Reals, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10][[1]]

eqns /. qq
```

Comment: Pls read [Subscript vs. Brackets](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99557/subscript-vs-brackets), [Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica?lq=1), maybe you want to edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you may have a problem with your constraints. In particular, numerical analysis suggests that your solutions have no solution for $0<k<1$. Below I will show you how I came to this conclusion.

---

First of all let's remove the `Subscript` variables. Although I don't think that they are the problem here, it is generally a Bad Idea to work with subscripted variables:

```
eqns /. Subscript[var_, num_] -> var[num];
```

I also like to work with lists of equations rather than logical combinations:

```
First@% /. And -> List;
```

Finally I am going to use `FindRoot`, which does not deal with mixtures of equations and inequalities, so I remove the constraints expressed as inequalities (I will reintroduce them in `FindRoot` though):

```
neweq = Select[%, Head[#] == Equal &]
```

> {c[2]+a[2] Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844]==5,3000 c[3]==7,5 (127-10 d)^2 a[3]+2 (-7+(6350-500 d) b[3]+1000 c[3])==0,10627269662 b[3]==2478589 a[2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844],6400000 a[3]==373 a[2] Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844],(127/10-d) a[3]+b[3]==(5 (1+(2457 k)/800))/8128,20048005 (6129+254 d (-5+c[2]))+20377872376 a[2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844]==0}

I am going to use FindRoot repeatedly on this system of equations, with randomly chosen starting values for the variables; I impose conditions on $d$ and $k$ in the corresponding `FindRoot` argument.

```
Reap@Do[
    Sow@Check[FindRoot[%,
       {{c[2], RandomReal[{-100, 100}]}, {c[3], RandomReal[{-100, 100}]},
        {a[2], RandomReal[{-100, 100}]}, {a[3], RandomReal[{-100, 100}]},
        {b[3], RandomReal[{-100, 100}]}, 
        {d, RandomReal[{0, 127/10}], 0, 127/10},
        {k, RandomReal[], 0, 1}},
       WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxIterations -> 1000
      ],
      Nothing
     ],
    {15000}
  ];

DeleteDuplicates[
 %[[2, 1, All, All, 2]],
 Round[#1, 0.0001] == Round[#2, 0.0001] &
]
```

During these calculations `FindRoot` repeatedly reports that the constraint on the value of $k$ cannot be satisfied:

> FindRoot::reged: The point {<<>>} is at the edge of the search region {0,1.000000000000000000000000} in coordinate 7 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

On the other hand, if the requirement that $0<k<1$ is removed, one repeatedly obtains the following solution set:

> {{-0.675532589367415, 0.00233333333333333, 1.46778950021966, 0.000330777133724070, 0.00127866724814811, 8.11721533270522, 1.15354224468521}}

As you can see, the value of $k$ that satisfied these equations (the last value in the list above) seems to be just slightly larger than $1$.