# Cannot evaluate differential in Mathematica

Tags: functions

I have a small toy script in Mathematica that I am trying to use to evaluate the pdf of $Y$ where $Y=X^2$, and $X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,a]$.

The script is,

```
assum = {a > 0}; 
Subscript[P, X][x_] := If[Inequality[0, Less, x, LessEqual, a], 1/a, 0];

Y[x_] := x^2

Subscript[F, Y][y_] := Integrate[If[Y[x] <= y, 1, 0]*Subscript[P, X][x], 
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Subscript[P, Y][y_] := D[Subscript[F, Y][y], y]
```

It shows the correct form of the pdf:

```
In[192]:=
Simplify[Subscript[P, Y][y], assum]

Out[192]=
Piecewise[{{1/(2*a*Sqrt[y]), y > 0 && a^2 >= y}}, 0]
```

However, it doesn't evaluate the expression correctly:

```
In[194]:=
Simplify[Subscript[P, Y][a*(a/2)], assum]

During evaluation of In[194]:= General::ivar:a^2/2 is not a valid variable. >>

Out[194]=
D[1/Sqrt[2], a^2/2]
```

The session, in pretty printing looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P[y]$ is defined to be $\partial_yF[y]$. If you now call $P[2]$ for example, this is translated to $\partial_2F[2]$, which of course does not make any sense.

One way to get around this behavior is not taking the derivative with respect to `y`, but with respect to the first argument instead. The following example assigns f[y] to be the derivative of g[y]:

```
g[y_] := y^2
f[y_] := Derivative[1][g][y]
f[x]
```

> ```
> 2 x
> ```

Instead of `Derivative[1][g][y]` you could also have used the shorthand notation `g'[y]`. Read the explicit long version I used as an operator applied to multiple things: `Derivative[1]` takes a function and calculates its first derivative with respect to the first argument. `Derivative[1][g]` is that derivative (as a pure function), and `Derivative[1][g][y]` is that pure function applied to a value `y`.

The script above has one problem however: Every time you call f[x], it re-calculates the derivative, which can take some time if your function is more complicated and you need a lot of data points. If you use functions instead of patterns (i.e. no `:=`) you can also get around this problem:

```
g = #^2 &
f = g'
f[x]
```

> ```
> #1^2 &
> 2 #1 &
> 2 x
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise `:=` wasn't the right way to define functions.

Comment: @highBandWidth err, both `=` and `:=` are right way to define functions. There is a big difference between them however, and you should learn the difference. See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-is-x-x-trickery and `SetDelayed`: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html

Comment: @tkott That's not really true. `=` and `:=` define pattern-based replacement rules, which may look like functions in many cases, but are handled differently internally. Defining actual functions is done using `Function`. Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns

Comment: @David Sorry you're absolutely right. I just used the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just keep your code the way it is (with the SetDelayed), but force the derivation to be executed at the definition by using `Evaluate`:

```
Subscript[P, Y][y_] := Evaluate[D[Subscript[F, Y][y], y]]
```

This gives you the correct result:

```
In[107]:= Simplify[Subscript[P, Y][a*(a/2)], assum]
Out[107]= 1/(Sqrt[2] a^2)
```

This would be the most robust way to do it (at least it is how the Mathematica 8 help does it).

Comment: This is how I would have done it, until I learned that one can also just use `Subscript[P, Y][y_] = D[Subscript[F, Y][y], y]`. The only difference to the original form is that I don't use `SetDelayed` but `Set`, so that the `y` is used literally and not replaced by its value at the time the "function" is called. This way is just a little shorter than using `Evaluate`.

Comment: True, but in general I try to avoid the use of `Set`, as it can give rise to difficult-to-debug naming conflicts.