# Scoping in assigning a derivative

Tags: assignment, scoping

While answering another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/cannot-evaluate-differential-in-mathematica), I stumbled upon a problem I cannot easily resolve.
To assign the derivative of a function to another function, typically one can do this with a `Set` or a `SetDelayed`:

```
f[x_]=D[Sin[x],x]
f2[x_]:=Evaluate@D[Sin[x],x]
```

Both give the same result, since forcing evaluating on a `SetDelayed`is essentially the same as using `Set`. However, **both** can give rise to naming conflicts, i.e.

```
x=7;
f[x_]=D[Sin[x],x]
f2[x_]:=Evaluate@D[Sin[x],x]
```

won't work. This bothers me a lot, because the reason I always use `SetDelayed`is to avoid this (sometimes difficult to find) type of bugs. So I tried to force some kind of local scoping, but until now didn't find a working solution. Using

```
f3[x_]:=Evaluate[Block[{x},D[Sin[x],x]]]
f4[x_]:=Evaluate[Module[{x},D[Sin[x],x]]]
f5[x_]:=Evaluate[With[{y=x},D[Sin[y],y]]]
```

doesn't work, because `Block` and `With` release the variable too fast and `Module` renames it locally (as can be seen by doing `?f3`, `?f4` or `?f5`).

What does work, is using

```
f6[x_] := With[{y = x}, Evaluate@D[Sin[y], y] /. y -> x]
```

And it works even when both `x` and `y` already have an assigned value. However, if we look at  its definition, we get:

```
?f6
Global`f6
f6[x_]:=With[{y=x},Evaluate[D[Sin[y],y]]/. y->x]
```

This is not what I want, because now the evaluation is delayed. Whenever my original function (here `Sin[x]`) is much more complicated, the derivation can take some time. If I need to calculate a lot of values of `f6`, this will stack up to a huge amount of time.

Any ideas to get a 'name-conflict-safe' derivative assignment which evaluates at its definition?

Comment: You should use `Derivative` instead of `D`, e.g. `f[x_] := Derivative[1][Sin][x]`.  See e.g. this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441#5441

Comment: @Artes: while I second your suggestion to use `Derivative` (see my answer), I think your example doesn't pre-evaluate the symbolic derivative which I think is what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Artes I don't think this is an exact duplicate as it specifically deals with scoping.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, I did not vote to close it, though scoping constructs are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This might work as you expect and be save even if definitions for `x` exist:

```
Block[{x}, f[x_] = D[Sin[x], x];]
```

I would strongly suggest that you get familiar with `Derivative` and pure functions if you work with symbolic derivatives, though. This will make your life much easier in the long term. Your example would reduce to:

```
f = Derivative[1][Sin]
```

and a more complicated example would also work, e.g.:

```
f = Derivative[1][Exp[# - Sin[#]] &]
```

or even:

```
g[x_] := Exp[x^2 + Sin[x]];
gprime = Derivative[1][g]
```

Comment: Beat me to it - +1.

Comment: @Leonid: pure luck :-), thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But what is then the formal difference between `D`and `Derivative`? Is it only in the way they are used? It looks like they are doing the same thing.

Comment: @freddieknets: yes, the way they are used is the main difference, but they are also not doing the exactly same thing: `Derivative` works with functions and the position in arguments while `D` works with expressions and the name of symbols.

Comment: What would be the solution if now f or g is a multivariate function such as f[x,y,z] for which we only want to derive partially, say, y

Comment: that would be `Derivative[0, 1, 0][f]`, see `ref/Derivative` in the Documentation Center for more information...

Answer (score 13):

You could use Formal Symbols:

```
f[\[FormalX]_] = D[Sin[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX]]
```

Which looks like this in the Notebook:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Formal Symbols are entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$x`<kbd>Esc</kbd> where `x` is any regular letter.

Formal Symbols cannot be assigned a global value, avoiding collisions:

> Set::wrsym: Symbol [FormalX] is Protected. >>

---

I also wrote [a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1997/121) `localSet` to answer a prior question which you could use:

```
x = 1.23;

localSet[ f[x_], D[Sin[x],x] ]

DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> Cos[x]}
> ```

Comment: Good point, I keep forgetting that these exist (I think the were introduced with version 7?). They seem to be made for such situations and need less explanation than other approaches. I don't have any indication that there would be problems, but do you have experience with using them in a larger piece of code?

Comment: @Albert yes regarding larger code, but nothing *large scale*.  There can still be collisions if you don't think through what you're doing in some cases, but they help tremendously, and are IMHO quite elegant in a case like this, when otherwise you have to jump through hoops to get a "safe" evaluation of the RHS.

Comment: +1 A while ago I encountered these Formal Symbols, but didn't see any use for them until now. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: the potential collisions are what I was concerned about. On the other hand such problems often don't even arise in practice as it would probably mean you really need to make abuse of those formal parameters to create any problems (like e.g. `Unprotect` them). Thanks for mentioning them, anyway.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, @Albert Just for avoiding some pitfalls: not all formal symbols are protected and are in the ``System` `` context (this is by design), cf. `\[FormalPhi]` vs. `\[FormalDelta]`. This definitely leaves room for potential collision.

Comment: @IstvánZachar: thanks for pointing that out, fortunately I was never using them in my code anyway :-). But why are you saying "this is by design"? It looks rather inconsistent to have two of them live in a different context and have different attributes than the rest...

Comment: @Albert TechSupport replied the following: "Some symbols may be used internally and therefore be protected. [...] `\[FormalPhi]` is in the `Global` context, which indicates that it is not being used internally."

Comment: @István Thanks for the note!  I was not aware of this.  Only the Formal Symbols based on the English alphabet are included in the Special Characters Palette; perhaps the Greek-base Symbols are not yet integrated?  There are lots of undocumented elements in the software that are not yet fully and reliably functional.