# Plotting a simple relationship with Plot[] results in empty graph

Tags: plotting, functions

I've moved this question over from StackExchange to get better visibility (and deleted the old question).

I have a user-defined relationship I'd like to plot:

```
a = (b + c)/d;
```

and I try to plot it as follows:

```
plotFunction[b_, c_] := Plot[a, {d, 0, 10}];
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

This results in an empty plot; only the axes are drawn.  Of course the following works fine:

```
plotFunction[b_, c_]:= Plot[(b + c)/d, {d, 0, 10}];
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

I don't understand why MMA refuses to draw the function in the first method?  I've tried using Show[] as well; no luck.  I even tried passing the relationship within the function as follow - no luck:

```
plotFunction[a_, b_, c_]:= Plot[a, {d, 0, 10}];
plotFunction[a, 2, 3]
```

I suppose it could have something to do with local vs global variable definitions inside and outside the function definitions?

Comment: Define a[b_,c_,d_] = (b + c)/d and use accordingly in Plot[].

Answer (score 12):

It's important to realize that when setting something up of the type:

```
f[x_]:=x
```

That you are setting a replacement rule, not creating a function. See [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns) for a further discussion of this.

In the current situation, what you wrote has the following effect. First, you define:

```
plotFunction[b_, c_] := Plot[a, {d, 0, 10}];
```

when you call

```
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

MMA does something like the following. "Oooh, I found a pattern that matches `plotFunction[b_, c_]`, I need to replace it, and then evaluate it!" Replacing it makes the right hand side look like:

```
Plot[a, {d, 0, 10}]
```

Since there wasn't anything for `b` and `c` to replace, the above is what MMA will now evaluate. Evaluating the expression, it says "Ooooh, oooh, I know how to deal with `a`!", so it replaces it:

```
Plot[(b + c)/d, {d, 0, 10}]
```

Then it tries to actually call the replacement-rule ("built-in-function") `Plot` which fails, since `b` and `c` are not numbers, as you saw. However, if you define:

```
a[b_,c_,d_]=(b + c)/d    
plotFunction[b_, c_] := Plot[a[b, c, d], {d, 0, 10}];
```

And call:

```
plotFunction[2, 3]
```

MMA first replaces `plotFunction` with:

```
Plot[a[2, 3, d], {d, 0, 10}]
```

Then evaluates that, at which point it sees that there is another pattern it knows how to deal with (`a[b_,c_,d_]=(b + c)/d`) and replaces that:

```
Plot[(2 + 3)/d, {d, 0, 10}]
```

And only then plots it, which results in the correct plot.

For dealing with these types of replacement problems, I strongly suggest the use of WReach's [traceView functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5527117#5527117). For Plots, this doesn't always help, but can be instructive.

Comment: I never imagined mma could be so eager and dramatic, but kudos for the imagery :)

Comment: @R.M See also http://xkcd.com/869/

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the solutions already posted, here's one you can use if you don't want to change the definition of `a` (e.g. because you've already used it a lot):

```
plotFunction[bb_,cc_]:=Block[{b=bb,c=cc},Plot[a,{d,0,10}]]
```

Now when you do

```
plotFunction[2,3]
```

the initial replacement will result in `Block[{b=2,c=3},Plot[a,{d,0,10}]]`. The `Block` construct temporarily binds the values of `b` and `c`, as can be seen by typing

```
Block[{b=2,c=3},{OwnValues[b],OwnValues[c]}]
(*
==> {{HoldPattern[b] :> 2}, {HoldPattern[c] :> 3}}
*)
```

Now the `Plot` will bind `d` to different values between `0` and `10` (it is really the global value of `d` which is changed, as can be seen by evaluating `Dynamic[d]` before starting the Plot command), and for each value of `d` evaluate `a`. Evaluation of `a` will first give the expression `(b+c)/d`, and since *at this point* there are `OwnValue` bindings for `b` and `c` (through `Block`) and `d` (through `Plot`), those are used to further evaluate this expression to (assuming e.g. `d` currently is `2.5`) `(2+3)/2.5` which then evaluates to `2.` and gives the point `{2.5,2.}` for the plot.

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation is that your main issue was simply a misunderstanding of what the arguments `b_`, `c_` etc mean in the definition of your plots. The underscore `_` marks them as "dummy variables" or "stand-ins" for the actual values passed to your `plotFunction`. That makes them completely independent of the *variables* named `b` and `c` on which your initial definition

```
a = (b + c)/d
```

relies. So if we start from the premise that you want to keep using this definition, then it would be less confusing to use different names for the "dummy variables" in `PlotFunction`. Not only less confusing, but also more useful, as we can already see in the answer by celtschk.

So I'll rename the function's dummy variables `bDummy` and `cDummy`, but then I have to tell the evaluator (i.e., the eager voice in tkott's narrative) what to do with these once we've been given actual values for them. Instead of defining a `Block`, you can do this as follows:

```
plotFunction[bDummy_, cDummy_] := 
       Plot[a /. {b -> bDummy, c -> cDummy}, {d, 0, 10}]
```

This uses a replacement rule: `/.` means `ReplaceAll` (see [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html)) and is followed by a list of rules like `b -> bDummy` which now instruct Mathematica to replace the *variable* (symbol) `b` by the value of `bDummy` at the time the function is called (and similarly for `c`).

It is quite important to know how one can define functions that interact with globally defined objects in addition to their "dummy variables", and replacement rules are a very common way of doing this. Basically, in this example they are used to "inject" the current values of the function argument into a previously defined expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
a[b_, c_] := (b + c)/d;
Plot[a[5, 3], {d, 0, 10}]
```

[image]