# How can I completely ban usage of some functions in output and mandate use of others?

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

For example, I hate that Mathematica uses `Pochhammer` symbol in outputs and prefer all the expressions in `Gamma` function. How can I ban usage of `Pochhammer`? I also want all outputs to use `HurwitzZeta` rather than `Zeta`.

In another instance I want the results to use my own variant of Polygamma function (modified). How can I mandate its usage when possible?

Comment: I cannot give an exact example right now, but I think it quite ofthen appears. I am looking for a general solution that would work everywhere.

Comment: There might be a way to set this as the default, but I think that `FunctionExpand[ expr ]` can take the argument `TargetFunctions->{Gamma,HurwitzZeta}`.

Comment: I want FullSimplify to follow these rules.

Comment: An example would be helpful, but what about `FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Gamma,HurwitzZeta}]`

Comment: @EliLansey I think that's `ComplexExpand` not  `FunctionExpand` (having `TargetFunctions` option). And there it can only take `{Re,Im,Abs,Arg,Conjugate,Sign}` as values.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I wasn't sure about that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 16):

You may try for example something like:

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Pochhammer, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e];
FullSimplify[Pochhammer[k, n], ComplexityFunction -> f]

(*
->Gamma[k + n]/Gamma[k]
*)
```

Comment: Does Mathematica provide access to the default complexity function, so you can just amend it instead of completely replacing?

Comment: @celtschk **LeafCount[]** IS the default Complexity function

Comment: What complexity is by default assigned to expressions that contain user's functions? Why user-defined functions always expanded to their definitions? Can it be avoided?

Comment: @Anixx With the default setting ComplexityFunction->Automatic, forms are ranked primarily according to their LeafCount, with corrections to treat integers with more digits as more complex.

Comment: What complexity is assigned to user-defined functions? Why they are always expanded?

Comment: @Anixx Because FullSimplify[expr] _tries a wide range of transformations on expr **involving elementary and special functions**, and returns the simplest form it finds._

Comment: @celtschk: not quite true that `LeafCount` is the default complexity function. As the docs `ref/ComplexityFunction` say, "forms are ranked primarily according to their LeafCount, with corrections to treat integers with more digits as more complex."

Comment: @belisarius so why it assigns high complexity to user-defined functions and expands them?

Comment: @Anixx Ohh, I understand you now. I think it should be related to the order in which the expression evaluates, but there are better experts here on Mma evaluation process. Perhaps you should post another question

Comment: @Anixx by user defined 'functions' do you mean things like `f[x_]:=Pochammer[x+1]`? If so, then the reason is that MMA replaces any instance of f[x] with the RHS (it is actually _not_ a `Function`), BEFORE any simplification is done (unless holds are in place), and hence doesn't know about simplification rules for it (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns). As to creating those rules: no idea

Comment: @celtschk, the default complexity function can be found in the *Properties & Relations* section of the `ComplexityFunction` documentation.

Comment: @SimonWoods: Indeed, there it  is. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you will find utility in [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html) and related functions?

```
Unprotect[Pochhammer];

Format[Pochhammer[k_, n_]] := HoldForm[ Gamma[k + n]/Gamma[k] ]

Protect[Pochhammer];

Pochhammer[a, b]
```

> ```
> Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a]
> ```

Similar things can be done with `$PrePrint`:

```
$PrePrint = # /. Pochhammer[k_, n_] :> HoldForm[ Gamma[k + n]/Gamma[k] ] &;

Pochhammer[a, b]
```

> ```
> Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I have found [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to be useful for when I want to replace instances of Gamma or Binomial calls to show as a factorial.

```
    x*Gamma[a] + x^2*Gamma[b] - 
  3*Binomial[z, c] /. {Gamma[n_] -> (n - 1)!, 
  Binomial[n_, k_] -> ((n)!/((n - k)!*k!))}
```

Out:

```
   x (-1 + a)! + x^2 (-1 + b)! - (3 z!)/(c! (-c + z)!)
```

Comment: but note that it's up to you to know that the replacement is equivalent.