# How to find and verify relationships between functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

MMa gave me a complicated result involving `Hypergeometric0F1`'s.  It was much less complicated after I discovered this identity:

```
Hypergeometric0F1[1, -x^2] = BesselJ[0, 2 x]
```

1) Is there a way to get MMa to validate relationships between functions, for example if I wasn't sure the identity above was true?

```
FullSimplify[Hypergeometric0F1[1, -x^2] - BesselJ[0, 2 x]]
```

does return 0, so that worked for the example, but `FullSimplify` failing to simplify something to 0 is not a solid proof.

2) Is there a way to tell MMa to convert (for example) all the Hypergeometric functions into whatever Bessel function form it can?

Comment: For your example you can also use `FunctionExpand[Hypergeometric0F1[1, -x^2]]`.

Comment: The second question is possibly a duplicate of: [(4281)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4281/121)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your second question, "Is there a way to tell MMa to convert (for example) all the Hypergeometric functions into whatever Bessel function form it can?", execute

```
$Post = FunctionExpand[#] &
```

at the beginning of a Notebook to cause `FunctionExpand` to be applied to the output of each `Cell` after it is executed.  However, be aware that `$Post = FunctionExpand[#] &` will do other things that you may not have in mind, such as converting `Log[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]` to `(Log[1 - x] + Log[1 + x])/2`.  Also, be aware that `$Post = FunctionExpand[#] &` in one notebook may affect evaluations in other notebooks sharing the same Kernel.

You also can use

```
$Post = FullSimplify[#] &
```

which automatically calls `FunctionExpand` and does other simplifications besides.  In this case even greater wariness may be warranted.

**Addenda**

Mr.Wizard kindly pointed out in a Comment that `$Post = FunctionExpand` has the same effect as `$Post = FunctionExpand[#] &`.  (Thanks!)

If the goal is to replace only `Hypergeometric0F1` with simpler expressions when possible without changing other functions, then

```
$Post = (# /. Hypergeometric0F1[z1_, z2_] :> FunctionExpand[Hypergeometric0F1[z1, z2]]) &
```

can be used.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this answer.  How does this help?  What of should I be wary?

Comment: @JerryGuern  Please see edit to my Answer.

Comment: There is no need to introduce `Function` here.  Simply `$Post = FunctionExpand` will do!