# Assessing argument type in set delayed function definitions

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, function-construction

I'm wondering how to properly assess the type of arguments passed to functions defined with `:=`. I want my functions to be the most efficient, unambiguous and clear as possible.

When hacking together a function, I don't really care about the type of each argument passed to that function. I'll use an example taken from [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html).

A first function draft would look like this:

```
>> g[x_] := Prime[x] - x
```

Which works fine as long as the type of the argument passed to it is compatible with `Prime`. The following is inappropriate behaviour, and should be fixed by changing the function definition:

```
>> {g[10], g["z"]}
<< {19, -"z" + Prime["z"]}
```

Here's where I don't know how to *correctly* proceed. Once I make sure my function works, by providing it arguments of the correct type, I can change its definition to

```
>> g[x_Integer] := Prime[x] - x
```

or

```
>> g[x_?IntegerQ] := Prime[x] - x
```

which both work as expected.

What's the difference between the two definitions, and which one should be used for maximum efficiency, robustness and cleanliness?

**Example with one of my functions**

This functions generates a set of points that, when passed to `Line`, draw a zig-zag. This case is more ambiguous than the previous.

I can define it this way, which works:

```
>> contactCoordinates[nCtc_Integer, x0_Integer, y0_Integer, 
   offset_?NumberQ] := 
    Table[{x, y0}, {x, x0, offset*nCtc, offset}]~Riffle~
     Table[{x, y0 + offset/2}, {x, x0 + offset/2, offset*nCtc, offset}]
```

I could also replace `_Integer` by `_?IntegerQ`, with no noticeable difference. The problem is with `_?NumberQ`. I can't define the function using `offset_Number` - I have either to use `offset_?NumberQ` or `offset_Real`. Is one better than the other?

---

1. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsForSomeCommonTypesOfExpression.html
2. [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922966/1142160

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121

Answer (score 18):

The differences between using `_Integer` and `_?IntegerQ` as to efficiency, robustness and cleanliness in my view are:

**Efficiency**

`_Integer` is more efficient. It belongs to what @LeonidShiffrin calls *syntactic patterns* and the evaluator doesn't need to be called to check if the pattern fits. On the other hand, `?` and `/;` require a call to the evaluator

**Robustness**

Both have their issues. `_?IntegerQ` will leak evaluation in cases where you might not want to. For example

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[_?IntegerQ]:=8;
```

Now, evaluating `f[Print@9]` will print the number 9, and that wouldn't happen with `_Integer`. This isn't only an issue if your symbol has a holding attribute, because the user might always call the function using `Unevaluated` and expect it not to leak

`_Integer`, however, has the disadvantage of matching something like `f[Integer[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]]` which is clearly not a good thing

The most robust solution I see is to fix `IntegerQ` using

```
f[_?(Function[i, IntegerQ@Unevaluated@i, HoldFirst])]:=8;
```

or to fix `_Integer` using

```
f[_Integer?(Function[i, AtomQ@Unevaluated@i, HoldFirst])]:=8;
```

If robustness is the priority, you probably can't avoid a call to the evaluator. It would be practical and neat to name a function

```
makeHolding[f_] := Function[Null, f@Unevaluated@##, HoldAll]
holdAtomQ= makeHolding[AtomQ]
```

and then just use `f[_Integer?holdAtomQ]`, `f[_Real?holdAtomQ]`, etc, or `f[_?(makeHolding[IntegerQ])]`

**Cleanliness**

Personally I like `_Integer` more in this regard but I think this is totally up to you

---

As to your example, all that comes to mind is the reminder that `NumberQ` won't match numbers like `Pi` while `NumericQ` will.

Also, as a sidenote, graphics primitives use real coordinates, and if you give them exact coordinates they have to save both versions of the numbers, in case you want to recover them. If you are not interested in keeping the original exact values in the front end, it may make sense to convert the parameters to approximate reals whatever form they came in. Just an idea

---

@jkuczm suggested in the comments using `Except[Integer[___], _Integer]`. This seems to me to be the best option. It will match only atoms of head `Integer` without calling the evaluator.

Comment: Quite thorough. +1

Comment: Really clarifying. +1

Comment: @Rojo There's also `Except[Integer@___, _Integer]` pattern which, as far as I know, is robust, and doesn't involve evaluator.

Comment: @jkuczm That seems right, a very nice solution.

Answer (score 12):

A key issue, I think, is that `PatternTest` must evaluate its argument to work, even if function holds its arguments.  Thus, there can be a huge difference in the timing between the two.  Here's an example:

```
pic := Plot3D[Sin[1/x] Cos[1/y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 100];
SetAttributes[f1, HoldFirst];
SetAttributes[f2, HoldFirst];
f1[x_Integer] := Prime[x] - x;
f2[x_?IntegerQ] := Prime[x] - x;
f1[pic] // Timing
f2[pic] // Timing
```

{6.*10^-6, f1[pic]}

{1.43547, f2[pic]}

When unanticipated, this type of evaluation is sometimes called an evaluation leak.  I would certainly use `Pattern` whenever possible, although `PatternTest` is more general.

Answer (score 9):

I think this question have gotten very good answers, but I just want to add my two cents to the topic.

`f[_sheep]` is a declarative typing, if something says it's a sheep, then it's a sheep, even if it doesn't make sense or will cause problems like: `sheep[wolf[]]`- Something which doesn't declare itself to be a Sheep isn't a Sheep even if you would suspect that it could perfectly well be assumed to be a sheep like `wholly[sheep[]]`.

`f[_?DuckQ]` is duck typing. If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it's a duck. So for example if we define `DuckQ[dog[]]=True` then `dog[]` is a Duck, and can be given to any function assuming arguments of the type `Duck[]`

Declarative typing will be more efficient, since you can deduce everything from the heads of the arguments. Duck typing is more flexible, and allows you to do type checking without explicit declaring the type of everything. A good example is matrixQ. You could explicitly state that your data is a matrix and define

```
f[_matrix]:=....
f[matrix[{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}]]
```

But most consider it nicer to just write out the structure as a list of lists, and use duck typing to check if it's a matrix.

An additional element of this is that declaritive typing as implimented in Mathematica does not allow type hiarchies, so You cannot define your function to accept animals `f[_animal]:=...` and expect it to work for `sheep[]` and `duck[]` but this can be handled easily by an appropriate "duck typed" definition `f[_?animalQ]:=...` with `animalQ[_sheep]=True;animalQ[_duck]=True`. Again showing the flexibility of defining boolean checks.

Comment: nice analogy :)

Comment: @CHM ambiguous in what sense? Maybe it could be improved.

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to answer "What's the difference between the two definitions, and which one should be used for maximum efficiency, robustness and cleanliness?".

The `PatternTest` approach is significantly more general, since the test can be arbitrarily complicated. Thus, we may define a function only for positive arguments that are even:

```
ClearAll@f;
f[x_?(# > 0 && EvenQ[#] &)] := 5

f[-2]
f[2]
f[3]
(*
f[-2]
5
f[3]
*)
```

Conversely, the more general approach may be slower, eg

```
ClearAll[f, g];
f[x_?IntegerQ] := x
g[x_Integer] := x

f[5] // timeIt
g[5] // timeIt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where `timeIt` is

```
ClearAll[timeIt];
SetAttributes[timeIt, HoldAll]
timeIt[expr_] := Module[{t = Timing[expr;][[1]], tries = 1},
    While[t < 1.,
    tries *= 2;
    t = AbsoluteTiming[Do[expr, {tries}];][[1]];
    ];
    Return[t/tries]]
```

Comment: do you know why `timeIt /@ {f[5], g[5]}` gives different answers vs. `{timeIt[f[5]], timeIt[g[5]]}` ? thanks

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi `timeIt` is `HoldAll`. In your map version, `f[5]` and `g[5]` get evaluated before  `timeIt` enters the game, because `Map` doesn't have a holding attribute. Try `timeIt/@Unevaluated@{f[5], g[5]}`