# What is the difference between defining a function and specifying the type of argument, versus applying a test to that argument?

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching

Say I want to create a function that evaluates differently based on what type of argument is given.  I've found two ways of doing this,

```
typefuncs := (f[x_List] := x~PadRight~3;
   f[x_Real] := x^2;
   f[x_Integer] := x - 2;);
testfuncs := (f[x_?ListQ] := x~PadRight~7;
   f[x_?IntegerQ] := x - 20;
   f[x_?NumberQ] := x^2.5;);
```

Interestingly, they both seem to work, but if you define the function one way first, trying to define it the other way will not stick:

```
ClearAll[f]
typefuncs
{f[{5}], f[5.7], f[5]}
testfuncs
{f[{5}], f[5.7], f[5]}
(* {{5, 0, 0}, 32.49, 3} *)
(* {{5, 0, 0}, 32.49, 3} *)
```

versus

```
ClearAll[f]
testfuncs
{f[{5}], f[5.7], f[5]}
typefuncs
{f[{5}], f[5.7], f[5]}
(* {{5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 77.5688, -15} *)
(* {{5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 77.5688, -15} *)
```

Which is the better practice for defining functions?  What is the fundamental difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### General

When you define a type based on a head, like

```
f[x_List, y_List]:=...
```

the test happens entirely in the pattern-matcher, not involving the main evaluator. I call such patterns "syntactic". Pattern tests on such patterns are usually faster or much faster. The reason is that all the matching happens entirely in the pattern-matcher, and the latter only needs to operate on the syntactic form of expression (`FullForm`), to establish the fact of the match. This can also be viewed as a strongest typing scheme available in Mathematica.

When you defined the patterns with `?` (`PatternTest`) or `/;` (`Condition`), you invite the main evaluator to join the game. So when you define a function like

```
f[x_?ListQ, y_?NumericQ]:=...,
```

the pattern-matcher always calls the main evaluator in order to pattern-match these patterns. Because of this, such tests are more general, but also can be significantly slower. They can also induce side effects, through the predicate's code executed by the main evaluator - which can't happen with the `_h` - style patterns.

#### Performance

Here is a comparison with a built-in atomic type (strings):

```
chars = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 100000];
MatchQ[chars, {___?StringQ}] // AbsoluteTiming
MatchQ[chars, {___String}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.018108, True} *)

(* {0.001687, True} *)
```

We can see an order of magnitude speed difference. This becomes even worse when the testing function is a little more complex:

```
ClearAll[f];
symtest  = f /@ Range[100000];
MatchQ[symtest, {___f}] // AbsoluteTiming
MatchQ[symtest, {___?(Function[Head[#] === f])}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.002725, True} *)

(* {0.087275, True} *)
```

The difference is most dramatic for packed arrays, where, in addition to the usual difference explained above, many pattern-testing system functions have been specially overloaded on certain patterns, so that they perform a constant-time check:

```
tst = Range[10000000];
MatchQ[tst, {___Integer}] // AbsoluteTiming
MatchQ[tst, {___?IntegerQ}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {5.*10^-6, True} *)

(* {2.4889, True} *)
```

#### Evaluation

The differences outlined above have implications for evaluation control. In particular, for functions which hold their argument, the "syntactic" patterns won't always work. For example:

```
ClearAll[a, f, g];
a = Range[10];
SetAttributes[{f,g}, HoldFirst];
f[l_List]:=l;
g[l_?ListQ]:=l;
{f[a], g[a]}

(* {f[a], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

The point is, that even though `a` *stores* a `List`, `f` can't check that by only using the pattern-matcher. In contrast to this, `g` calls the main evaluator, which confirms that `a` evaluates to a `List`.

This effect has also another side: when you use a pattern like `a_List` in a `Hold*` - function, you can be sure that there will be no evaluation leaks, while in cases where you use the tests based on `Condition` or `PatternTest`, you have to make an extra effort to ensure that (if that is desired). For example:

```
ClearAll[a];
a := Print["Leak!"]
Cases[Unevaluated[{a, {a, {a}}}], s_List :> Hold[s], Infinity, Heads -> True]

(* {Hold[{a}], Hold[{a, {a}}]} *)
```

while

```
Cases[Unevaluated[{a, {a, {a}}}], s_?ListQ :> Hold[s], Infinity, Heads -> True]
```

> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!
>
> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!
>
> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!
>
> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!
>
> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!
>
> During evaluation of In[296]:= Leak!

```
(* Out[299]= {Hold[{a}], Hold[{a, {a}}]} *)
```

In this particular case, one would have to write someting like this, to avoid the leaks:

```
Cases[
   Unevaluated[{a, {a, {a}}}], 
   s_?(Function[Null, ListQ[Unevaluated[#]], HoldAll]) :> Hold[s], 
   Infinity, 
   Heads -> True
]

(* {Hold[{a}], Hold[{a, {a}}]} *)
```

#### Pre-filtering

It is often useful to use the `_h` patterns even if they are not enough be themselves, for pre-filtering purposes.

Here is an example - first, a simple custom test for a list:

```
ClearAll[smallListQ];
smallListQ[x_ /; ListQ[x] && Length[x] < 20 && Total[x^2] < 1000] := True;
smallListQ[_] := False
```

Now, the same test, but with the part of a pattern using `_h` idiom:

```
ClearAll[smallListQBetter];
smallListQBetter[x_List /; Length[x] < 20 && Total[x^2] < 1000] := True;
smallListQBetter[_] := False
```

Compare performance:

```
smallListQ /@ Range[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.153377, Null} *)

smallListQBetter /@ Range[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.058185, Null} *)
```

In some cases, the difference may be far greater

#### When to use which

- Whenever you can get away with purely "syntactic" tests, surely du use them.
- Also, they can often be used when you defined a custom data type based on some head, used as a container for data. In those cases, the `_h` test serves as a test for a given data type.
- Often you can't avoid using the `_?predicate` or `x_/;predicate[x]` types of patterns, because the tests must call the main evaluator, for whatever reason. Just be aware of performance and evaluation control - related implications of this method
- Often one can combine both styles, using the `_h` - style patterns as a pre-filtering device. This can improve both the robustness of the code (stronger typing), and the performance.

#### Related discussions

- [How can I ensure that I am constructing patterns in the most efficient way possible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-am-constructing-patterns-in-the-most-efficient-way-possi)
- [How are Memberq and Freeq so fast](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/how-are-memberq-and-freeq-so-fast)
- [Assessing argument type in SetDelayed function definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/assessing-argument-type-in-set-delayed-function-definitions)

Comment: Do you have those answers pre-written somewhere? :)

Comment: I thought that was you. +1, because you're obviously here just for the points. :)

Comment: @Kuba, maybe he accidentally saved the files for his book here instead of his hard drive... :)

Comment: @Kuba I sure do. In my head :)

Comment: @rcollyer I think there are only a handful of people here on the site who still remember my true motives, obviously you being one of them :)

Comment: Yes, and some of them read ol' answers [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues/545#545) and Comments, well.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - is there a good Q&A that discusses the practical differences between using `PatternTest` and `Condition` for defining a series of `DownValues`?  Both bring the evaluator into play, but I wonder if there is a reason to prefer `f[x_ /; test[x]]` over `f[x_?test]`.

Comment: @JasonB. [1] I can't recall such a discussion, although it might be hidden somewhere on this site. One clear difference is that `Condition` can be applied to a pattern involving several variables, like `f[x_, y_] /; x < y`, while with `PatternTest`, a similar thing would be more clunky. Another difference is that it is somewhat easier to control evaluation (leaks) with `Condition`, like e.g. ``Cases[Unevaluated[expr], s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "System`" :> Hold[s], Infinity]``, while for `PatternTest` one would have something like ``Function[sym, Context[sym] === "System`", HoldFirst]``, ...

Comment: @JasonB. [2] ... and it is far easier to forget using this long `Function` syntax with `PatternTest` - while in `Condition`, this problem does not exist, because there is no extra parameter-passing stage, where evaluation leak may happen. In terms of speed, `PatternTest` tends to be slightly faster, but if that difference starts to really be important, then may be pattern-matching is a wrong tool for that problem altogether. In terms of readability, I personally tend to use `PatternTest` a lot with predicates, like `f[_?EvenQ]`, it is brief and clear. But this is largely a matter of  taste.

Comment: @JasonB. [3] A bit more on evaluation leaks: in my example above, if `Context` didn't have a `HoldFirst` attribute, I would have had to use `Unevaluated` in both examples: `s_Symbol /; someFunction[Unevaluated[s]]` and `Function[sym, someFunction[Unevaluated @ sym], HoldFirst]`, which is what one generally needs to do to ensure safe passing of arguments to predicates without their premature evaluation (whenever that is important, which is in general not very often). Anyway, I personally tend to use `PatternTest` pretty much always, for a single-arg tests, and `Condition` for multi-arg tests.

Comment: @JasonB.[4]  Note also: `Condition` can be used in an extended rule / function definition syntax with so-called shared local variables, for example `x_Integer :> With[{result = x ^2}, f[result] /; result > 100]`, in which case `Condition` is still considered a part of the pattern, even though it is used inside `With` (can also be `Module` or `Block`), and operates on a local variable. If the condition is not fulfilled, the whole rule is considered not applicable by the patter-matcher, which goes on to try the next rule (if available), or returns an expression back, as if no evaluation ...

Comment: @JasonB.[5] ... took place, even though there clearly were intermediate evaluations like `result = x ^ 2` happening in the process of resolving the `Condition`. This is a powerful feature associated specifically with `Condition` and not `PatternTest`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - thank you (again) for the detailed response.

Comment: @JasonB. Was glad to help.