# Attributes with Pattern test

Tags: functions, attributes

Probably this question has no application but it helps understand basic issues about `Attributes` and functions.

I was writing a piece of code where I accidently defined a function like this:

```
ClearAll[f1]
SetAttributes[f1, HoldAll]
f1[list_List] := "evaluated"
```

When evaluated I get results as expected:

```
f1[{1, 2}]
(*"evaluated"*)
l={1,2};
 f1[l]
(*f1[l]*)
```

But when I tried to check if this works with Pattern test I was surprised that evaluation happened in the function argument:

```
ClearAll[f2]
SetAttributes[f2, HoldAll]
f2[list_?(Head[#] == List &)] := "evaluated"
f2[{1, 2}]
(*"evaluated"*)
f2[l]
(*"evaluated"*)
```

Same result with Pattern Condition `/;`

My question is that what kind of behavior is this and why does not `HoldAll` hold the argument (which I understand is anything inside the brackets `[]` of the function) from evaluation and is this behavior same for all other `Attributes`?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI this is discussed in the *Possible Issues* section of the [`PatternTest` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)

Comment: @SimonWoods Good to know, thanks. I wasn't aware that this has been discussed in the docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### General explanation

The semantics of `PatternTest` and `Condition` is that the main evaluator is called to test the pattern, when those are used. It is called internally by the pattern-matcher, and this call is independent from the main evaluation procedure for the main expression. The reason is that the evaluations used to determine the pattern match should be considered sub-evaluations, rather than a part of the standard evaluation procedure for the main expression being evaluated.

This means that `Hold*` - attributes don't prevent evaluation requested by the pattern-matcher to test the fact of the match. This is one reason why one has to be careful when using such tests, to avoid evaluation leaks introduced through `Condition` and `PatternTest` via the pattern-matcher. In particular, you may want to use the construct like

```
f2[list_?(Function[Null, Head[Unevaluated @ #] == List, HoldAll])] := "evaluated"
```

to make it roughly equivalent to the first pattern you considered.

#### Relevant Links

- Apparently, as noted by [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) in comments, this issue is discussed in the *Possible issues* section of the `PatternTest` [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)
- A related discussion in a very similar context can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101714/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-a-function-and-specifying-the-type-of-ar/101720#101720)
- I have considered a similar situation also in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1579/81).

Comment: Clear but one more thing to make it fully clear. if the function is defined like this: `f2[list_List?(Head[#] == List &)] := "evaluated"` then no evaluation happened and the `PatternTest`  is not able to call  the evaluator .

Comment: @Algohi Yes, because `_List` acts as a prefiltering device. This means that the pattern-matcher stops at that point and does not need to call the test function, because it rejects the pattern at an earlier stage of  `_List`.

Comment: Aha, it is like that the checking of the argument starts and proceed sequentially. If one pattern/condition passed than proceed to the next.

Comment: @Algohi I'd rather say that for patterns of the type `p_head /; test[p]` or `p_head?test`, the procedure to match the pattern is that first, the `p_head` part is tested, and if the pattern doesn't match, the test from `Condition` or `PatternTest` is simply not performed. So yes, this is a particular form of short-circuiting, very sensible one IMO. I have discussed it in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101720).