# Difference between function definitions

Tags: functions, function-construction, core-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns)

I thought about describing the context in which I faced this problem, but I figured it is general enough and clear enough to pose it as it is.

> What is the difference between the two following definitions:
>
> ```
> f[x_]:=Sin[x]
> g=Sin[#]&
> ```
>
> Under what circumstances will the two behave differently? Is any of them preferable as a general practice?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  well, there are the much better answers!

Comment: @YvesKlett At the time that one was asked, we had a lot of energy since we were only out there for a week :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin question on best practice: since my answer is now quite redundant and I am voting to close, should I delete the answer?

Comment: @YvesKlett Since the question is likely going to be closed,I think that does not matter much.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't find the duplicate when I searched for an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @yohbs What is funny is that I knew precisely the name of the question (functions vs patterns), but when I typed that in SE search, I got nothing. So, I had to look for my past answers to locate it, since I recalled contributing an answer there. SE search quite often sucks.

Comment: I also searched superficially and did not find the answer...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin True that. Googling with `site:mathematica.stackexchange.com` added to the search terms is often better.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Agree.

Answer (score 1):

Very short answer on one relevant difference (probably much better ones will appear):

A pure function like `g` will be faster performance-wise, because it gets rid of all the overhead (e.g. pattern matching) involved in the definition of `f`.