# Compiling a function depending on an external function

Tags: compile

Consider the simple case:

```
g[x] := x^3;
f[x] := x^2 + g[x];
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2 + g[x]]
```

Evaluating the two functions, Mathematica complains that the second depends on the function `g[x]`, saying:

> CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

Which is the correct way to compile the function `f` in this case?

Comment: `Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate[x^2 + g[x]]]`

Comment: I get no error in V12 from `g[x_] := x^3; cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2 + g[x]]`, although it and @ilian's suggestion both contain `MainEvaluate[]`. Note the argument to `g` is a pattern `x_`, not a symbol `x`.

Comment: @ilian I wouldn't do that, without at least wrapping a `Block[{x}, ...]` around `Compile`. But even then, I think it is generally an error - prone practice, unless you are in full control of exact evaluation path for the stuff inside `Evaluate`.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm happy to retract my attempt at commenting

Comment: @ilian I didn't at all mean to discourage your comments, I hope it didn't sound like that.

Comment: Not at all, I had just wanted to mention "InlineExternalDefinitions" which the answer already does.

Comment: A bit cumbersome but very robust is this way: `Block[{x}, With[{code = x^2 + g[x]}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, code]]]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Long time ago I wrote a macro, which expands global `DownValues` - based definitions, called `withGlobalFunctions`. It can be found at the end of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/746/81). With it, all you need to do is wrap the `Compile` call like this:

```
g[x] := x^3;
f[x] := x^2 + g[x];
cf = withGlobalFunctions @ Compile[{{x, _Real}}, f[x]]
```

This has the advantage over `Evaluate` advice in that you can't leak a global value for `x` in, even if it exists. And it has an advantage over `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` advice in that it expands arbitrary long chains of calls.

The limitation of this approach is that patterns in function definitions you may want to inline / expand in this way, better be very simple, involving blanks but not much else. This is because what this does is a kind of a macro-expansion, without actual evaluation involved. So that expansion will get stuck if patterns do any non-trivial checks.

`withGlobalFunctions` can trivially be extended to expand definitions based on other `...Values`. As written, it only expands definitions from `` Global` `` context, but that restriction can be removed or lifted as well.

Comment: So what good is `"InlineExternalDefinitions->True"` when `withGlobalFunctions` is superior in every way?  Why can't `"InlineExternalDefinitions->True"` simply call `withGlobalFunctions`?

Comment: @QuantumDot I don't know. `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` is a built-in option. Perhaps the developers wanted to play it safe, and limit it in scope. As to your last question, it is largely rhetorical, since `withGlobalFunctions` is not a built-in. OTOH, anyone is free to define their own wrapper around `Compile`, which could do that.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that you were a developer.

Comment: @QuantumDot Not of `Compile`, no.