# Performance of pure function - Best way to define a function?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, functional-style, pure-function

In general, to define a function, we often use `f[x_]`. Another way is to use pure function (full form and shorthand). I want to test the performance of these function declaration.

**Original test:**

Here is a simple test:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4];

f1[x_] = 3 x;
f2[x_] := 3 x;
f3 = Function[x, 3 x];
f4 = (3 #) &;

l1 = Range[10^7];

f1 /@ l1; // Timing
f2 /@ l1; // Timing
f3 /@ l1; // Timing
f4 /@ l1; // Timing

f1[l1]; // Timing
f2[l1]; // Timing
f3[l1]; // Timing
f4[l1]; // Timing
```

And here is a result:

```
{5.04688, Null}

{5.29688, Null}

{0.21875, Null}

{0.171875, Null}

{0., Null}

{0.015625, Null}

{0., Null}

{0., Null}
```

So here is what I've learned: (It's not new here, many people have shown it).

**1. Use built-in Listability:**
`f1[l1]` is much faster than  `f1 /@ l1`;

**2. Pure function is the fastest solution**
`f4 = (3 #) &`; is faster than `f3 = Function[x, 3 x];`, and faster than `f2[x_] := 3 x;`

**3. Searching the global rule definition is costly**
`f2[x_] := 3 x;` searching global rule is inside the loop.

```
f2 /@ l1; // Timing
{5.29688, Null}


f3 /@ l1; // Timing
{0.21875, Null}
```

**Update 1:**
To avoid the built-in Listable over a list, I change the definition.

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4];

f1[x_] = something[x];
f2[x_] := something[x];
f3 = Function[x, something[x]];
f4 = (something[#]) &;
```

Repeat these functions on a list:

```
l1 = Range[10^6];

f1 /@ l1; // Timing
f2 /@ l1; // Timing
f3 /@ l1; // Timing
f4 /@ l1; // Timing
```

Here is what I get:

```
{0.390625, Null}

{0.390625, Null}

{0.5, Null}

{0.296875, Null}
```

The pure function shorthand is the fastest. And the classic function declaration is very slow (50 times slower). I wonder why? Is it due to the `x Pattern`, or due to the difference between `Set` and `SetDelay`?

When do I need to do an intensive calculation, which type of function declaration I should use?

**Conclusion:**
I found that using pure function is very fast. Adding the global rewrite rule in the inner loop is slow. Each time we define a new function, a rewrite rule is added. Term rewriting is expensive inside the loop. (For the built-in function, don't forget the Listability). For the complex function, use `/@` combined with pure function.

Comment: seen [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/704/125)?

Comment: The function `f1` doesn't work and is defined incorrectly. Try evaluating `f1[1]` to see what I mean.

Comment: oh, thank you. This is a duplicated question I think. Sorry for that.

Comment: Once `f1` is reparied, you should also try `f1[l1]`, `f2[l1]`, `f3[l1]`, and `f4[l1]` to become fully confused... ;)  Explanation: `Plus` and `Times` have the attribute `Listable` which circumvents almost all of the calling overhead.

Comment: Thank you. :D. Most built-in Mathematica function is "internal listable", that's why they are so fast. By reading another post, I see that Function declaration is much faster than the global rewrite rule f[x_]