# Defined function takes more time than pure/anonymous function. Why?

Tags: function-construction, timing

A function defined by `f[x_]:=<code>` and applied on every element of a list as `f /@ testList` seems to take longer than the same anonymous function applied as `Function[x,<code>] /@ testList`. Why is that? Is there some extra copying of variables in the first case? Is it not the correct way to define functions?

## MWE: Signed volumes

As a MWE, consider a function computing a signed volume defined as follows:

```
signedVol[lst_] := Det@Table[lst[[i]] - lst[[1]], {i, 2, Length@lst}]
```

Generate testing data as 100'000 quadruples of points in 3D:

```
testList = Table[RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {4, 3}], {i, 1, 100000}];
```

And compare the following two evaluations. In the second, we just replace `signedVol` by an anonymous function with identical definition:

```
time = Now; signedVol /@ testList; Print[Now - time]
time = Now; Function[lst, Det@Table[lst[[i]] - lst[[1]], {i, 2, Length@lst}]] /@ testList; Print[Now - time]
```

On my computer, I am consistently getting ~0.8s for the former, and ~0.3s for the latter. I also tried for 1'000'000 quadruples, and got a consistent ratio, 9.1s vs 2.9s.

## Question

Why is there such a big difference? Is defining a function like this somehow wrong?

I also tried defining `signedVol=Function[lst, <code>]` and then applying it, which gave me the same results as applying the anonymous function directly (the latter case). So this seems to be a viable option for fast computations with a predefined function. However, I have never seen this being used, and it feels like a strange construction. Is this something people use?

## Version and system

I am using Mathematica 12.3.1 for macOS, and I am on macOS Monterey 12.1

## Additional example

I also defined the same computation by my own explicit formula for the 3D case as follows

```
signedVol3D[lst_] := (
     (lst[[2, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[3, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[4, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    + (lst[[4, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[2, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[3, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    + (lst[[3, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[4, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[2, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    - (lst[[4, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[3, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[2, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    - (lst[[2, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[4, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[3, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    - (lst[[3, 1]] - lst[[1, 1]])*(lst[[2, 2]] - 
      lst[[1, 2]])*(lst[[4, 3]] - lst[[1, 3]])
    )
```

I did the same experiment as with `signedVol` and the times are as follows

| Code used | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `signedVol /@ testList` | 0.83 seconds |
| `Function[lst, <code of signedVol>] /@ testList` | 0.26 seconds |
| `signedVol3D /@ testList` | 2.30 seconds |
| `Function[lst, <code of signedVol3D>] /@ testList` | 0.05 seconds |

Interestingly, `signedVol3D` performs worse than `signedVol`, but the anonymous version of `signedVol3D` performs better than the anonymous version of `signedVol`.

## Remark on timing method used

Note that I use the construction `time = Now; <code>; Print[Now - time]` instead of `Timing`, because `Timing` seems to have some unexpected behavior when you run it several times in the same cell -- for example if you run it on the same code multiple times in the same cell, the first evaluation yields faster time than all the following. But there is already a separate question about that.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/5478

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* is a pattern matching and rewriting language. Defining the function as an ownvalue of `f` means that to use it, you only have to invoke the simplest part of the pattern matching machinery. For `f[x_]` the machinery, at least in principle, first has to check for an ownvalue of `f`, and then check downvalues for a match (more complicated). I believe this is behind the effect here.

Comment: John, while you make a valid point, it could not possibly account for such dramatic time differences. This clearly looks like the effect of auto-compilation of `Function[...]` - based versions, in this particular case - as discussed in more detail in the Q/A linked by @Kuba.