# Keywords to find documentation for this syntax

Tags: evaluation, documentation

*Mathematica* allows this syntax, but I cannot find any documentation (or books) that discuss the various uses/advantages of it

```
g[1] := Plus;
g[2] := Times;
g[1][3, 5]
(* 8 *)

g[2][3, 5]
(* 15 *)
```

What keywords can I use to find this in the documentation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Let me remind you three things we 
usually do here: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering 
questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 
3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), 
because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users 
sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves 
your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 12):

Your `g[1]` and `g[2]` are simply acting as `Head`:

```
g[1] := Plus;
```

So there is no mystery in this syntax:

```
 {g[1][a, b], Plus[a, b]}
```

> {a + b, a + b}

```
 Head /@ {g[1][a, b], Plus[a, b]}
```

> {Plus, Plus}

So you need to read:

- [Head](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html)
- [Everything Is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)

But maybe there is a bit more to it than meets the eye. You actually almost wondered into programming concept called [**Currying**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) which according to Wikipedia "is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument (partial application)."

So you can do things like:

```
f[x_][y_] := Sin[x y]

f[x] /@ Range[5]
```

> {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin[5 x]}

Documentation mentions it [**here**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0h2n4bbur6-p9). For deeper insight see [**discussion**](http://books.google.com/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&pg=PA74) in @SalMangano "Mathematica Cookbook".

BTW, @acl [nice addition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9741/keywords-to-find-documentation-for-this-syntax/9743#9743) (to see how Mathematica thinks) can be visualized as

```
TreeForm[Trace[g[1][a, b]]]
```

[image]

So the thinking goes from top to bottom and from left to right.

Comment: If you're mentioning Currying, then you might add in a word or two and some links to `SubValues` (I remember there were a few posts here too)

Comment: @R.M `SubValues` (the function) isn't in the documentation, but here's a nice [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52) which covers them.

Comment: @rcollyer Right, that and [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/5) are the ones that I remembered

Comment: @R.M I had forgotten about that one.

Comment: the discussion on currying I think deserves an upvote, but I can't upvote twice

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Vitaliy's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9742/16): You can see what happens with

```
g[1] := Plus;
FullForm /@ (g[1][3, 4] // Trace)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, on evaluating `g[1][3,4]`, Mathematica looks up `g[1]` and sees it evaluates to `Plus`; it's then left with `Plus[3,4]` which evaluates to `7`.

Comment: +1 Cool idea to use Trace. I referred to your answer too ;-)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov does that mean the entire fabric of reality is going to rip apart? Or, just stackexchange?

Comment: @rcollyer This just means that you need to answer too and do a three way cross-referencing

Comment: @R.M there's a French term for that, but I don't think it is appropriate for polite company.

Comment: @rcollyer it just means household of three so I don't see the problem :)

Comment: @rcollyer I was thinking of a Mexican standoff, but a ménage à trois is equally appropriate, I guess

Comment: @R.M make love not war, etc

Comment: @acl an older professor of mine has been giving talks on ménage à trois in quantum mechanics, and yes he uses that exact term and enjoys the laughter he gets from it. I am very sorry I didn't take more classes with him as he was a brilliant teacher when I had him.