# How can I overload a function with multiple bracket-slots so f[a][b] and f[a] can coexist?

Tags: programming, function-construction, variable-definitions, argument-patterns

Maybe this is not even possible:

I want to create a function `f` that can have two input brackets like:

```
f[a_][b_:1]:= a*b
```

and alternatively just one input bracket:

```
f[a_]:= a
```

But with overloading the definitions the second definition interferes with the first definition, because the pattern f[a_] is replaced in a expression like:

In:

```
f[2][3]
```

Out:

```
2[3]
```

with the result of f[2] (in this case)

Of course, I could use just one bracket slot like `f[a_,b_:1]`, instead of `f[a_][b_:1]`, but thats not the point.

So i am asking for an optional bracket slot. Is that possible?

(BTW, I dont know the correct name of the []-Pattern, and called it bracket slot)

Comment: Just curious, why not `f[a_]` and `f[a_, b_]`, or two different functions?

Comment: Related: [(5686494)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494/618728),  [(544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121), [(9741)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9741/121), [(42030)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42030/121)

Comment: @2012rcampion i know that this is a very special case, but sometimes i want to have both possibilities with the same function.

Comment: @sacratus It actually seems rather natural to me, though in my opinion one must choose between this syntax and [Currying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686494/currying-with-mathematica) as using them concurrently (not for the same function) would be quite confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the Standard Evaluation Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html) the heads of expressions are evaluated first:

1. If the expression is a raw object (e.g., Integer, String, etc.), leave it unchanged.
2. Evaluate the head h of the expression.
3. Evaluate each element of the expression in turn ...

Therefore since `f[1]` is the head of `f[1][2]` it will evaluate if it has a definition that matches.  This is unavoidable in standard evaluation.  To get around this requires [`Stack`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Stack.html) trickery that Leonid [illustrated here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/545/121).  It works on the principle that `f` is the head of `f[1]` itself and is therefore evaluated first of all.

Here is a meta-function to automate his method:

```
SetAttributes[deepDefine, HoldAll]

deepDefine[s_Symbol, LHS_, RHS_] :=
  s :=
   With[{stack = Stack[_]},
    With[{fcallArgs = Cases[stack, HoldForm[LHS] :> RHS]},
     (First@fcallArgs &) & /; fcallArgs =!= {}
    ]
   ]
```

We now apply it like this:

```
ClearAll[f]

deepDefine[f, f[a_][b_: 1], a*b]

f[a_] := a
```

Test:

```
f[x]
f[x][y]
f[z][]
```

> ```
> x
>
> x y
>
> z
> ```

Comment: wow, this is impressive! i did not expected, that one found a solution for this. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @sacratus All the credit for this method goes to Leonid; please vote for his answer.  I just "put a ribbon on it" with `deepDefine`. :-)

Comment: I allready upvoted Leonids answer, but refering to a good existing answer is also honorable :-)

Comment: @sacratus: just as an advice, I think you really should think about the last sentence in Leonids answer before building "prodution code" that relies on `Stack`...