# Double arguments and place of the underscore

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

Could someone explain me of this bit of code below is correct:

- Is it possible to define a function with a second bracket, see below, i.e. `f[x_][y_]`? And what does this implement?
- What does the syntax `[C_s]` do?

  ```
  i[a_,b_][C_s]:=ReplacePart[C,{a->C[[b]],b->C[[a]]}]
  ```

*Edit*

So let me a bit more detailed:

This is the code I want to understand, and that has to implement the function 
$$ S_{1,2} = \frac{i}{h(x)}\mathbb{P}_{1,2}+\mathbb{I}_{1,2}\,,$$
where $\mathbb{P}_{1,2}$ is the permutation operator and $\mathbb{I}_{1,2}$ is the identity operator, acting on the state 1 and state 2, of a three particle state defined by:

```
probe=s[{a1,x1},{a2,x2},{a3,x3}];
```

The code is the following:

```
i[a_,b_][C_s]:=ReplacePart[C,{a->C[[b]],b->C[[a]]}]
p[a_,b_][C_s]:=ReplacePart[C,{{a,2}->C[[b,2]],{b,2}->C[[a,2]]}]
S[a_,b_][A]:=A/.Cs:>Block[{xa=C[[a,2]],xb=C[[b,2]]},(I/h[xa-xb])p[a,b][C]+i[a,b][C]]
```

I do not understand how the last line can work; what is de `Cs' referring to?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, although you may want to use the format carefully. A possible duplicate: [How can I overload a function with multiple bracket-slots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76008/27951). See also: [(5686494 on StackOverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494), [(9741)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9741/27951), [(544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/27951).

Comment: In this particular example, I think the *s* after the `C_` is not valid.  You could have `C_List` and then only arguments of type `List` would work there.  But I don't know of a `s` type

Comment: @Jason It should be clarified that it's only invalid (or, more accurately, not useful) _by default_ -- if the user has implemented, or intends to implement/use the head `s`, then it's perfectly valid to use `C_s` in a pattern.  It means a single argument with head ('type') `s`.

Comment: Is it possible you meant for `C_s` to actually read `C_S`?  As written, it will match to `s[...]` but not `S[...]`.

Comment: Don't use `C` - it's a reserved symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question:  See [How can I overload a function with multiple bracket-slots so f[a][b] and f[a] can coexist?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76008/11035), and the comments.

Second question:  Without the `s`, `C_` is a pattern which we can call `C` on the right hand side.  (It seems like you understand this.)

With the `s` included, `C_s` is likewise a pattern that we can call `C`, but it only matches expressions with head `s`.  (Head might be thought of like 'type' in other languages.)  You can test the head of any expressions with

```
Head/@{ f[x], f[x][y], {x}, x+y, x*y, x }
```

> {f, f[x], List, Plus, Times, Symbol}

The quick answer is that `C_s` will only match an expression that looks like `s[ ... ]`.  Thus, you get something like this:

```
f[x_][C_s] := foo[ x, C ]

f[x][ y ]
```

> f[x][y]

```
f[x][ s[y] ]
```

> foo[ x, s[y] ]

Note that `C` on the right hand side includes both the symbol `s` and its arguments.

Be careful of

```
f[x][ s ]
```

> f[x][s]

This is because `Head[s]` evaluates to `Symbol`.  This is true even if you have definitions for things like `s[x_]`, as long as `s` itself hasn't been given definitions with `=` or `:=`.

**Edit**

(I initially misread the question, and thought 'Cs' referred to the individual `C`'s and `s`'s, not the symbol `Cs`.)

Addressing the last line of the question, `Cs` is not defined anywhere in the code you've given.  As written, the right hand side of the last line will replace literal occurrences of `Cs` with `Block[...]`.

However, since the left hand side of the `:=` contains `A` and not `A_`, the only possible value of `A` on the right hand side is the literal symbol `A`.  (It is very likely this is a mistake.)