# what is the difference between these definitions?

Tags: functions

I define 2 functions:

```
g[s_][x_,y_] := the gaussian  (1)

g1[s_,x_,y_] := the gaussian  (2)
```

I get the same answer using `g[s][ x, y]` and `g1[ s, x, y]`.
So, what is the difference?
Is there some advantage to be gained in definition `1` over `2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121

Comment: On the surface, not much. But, they are treated differently by the [evaluator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52), the second (a downvalue) being evaluated before the first (a subvalue). Also, you can add an attribute to a downvalue, but not to a subvalue, without some [contortions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/52).