# What is the meaning of two square brackets in function definition?

Tags: function-construction

I came along the following function definition

```
f[a_, b_, c_][r_] = ...
```

with some function on the right hand side. Is this equivalent to

```
f[a_, b_, c_,r_] = ...
```

or

```
f[{a_, b_, c_},r_] = ...
```

?

If so, what are the advantages or field of use of these different definitions? Are there more possibilities?

Comment: No, these are not equivalent.  Why don't you *try* the different forms and discover the differences. Great way to make the learning stick.

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28703/what-is-the-difference-between-these-definitions?lq=1)

Comment: agree @ rasher, with trying the different forms this I have tried to convey in my answer to encourage @wondering.

Answer (score 3):

Example 3 is very different from example 1 and 2.

Example 2 is a function with 4 arguments whereas example 3 has two arguments, first argument is a list with three elements{a_,b_,c_} and 2nd argument is r.

Function names are in Mathematica not only defined by their names but by their name,structure of arguments and the names of the arguments.

Comparing example 1 and 2, they both called like a function with 4 arguments. Example 1 with the double brackets works because function definition are stored as rules in Mathematica and evaluated by the kernel's pattern matching engine.
However example 1 seems awakened to me, because it complicates the syntax without adding any benefit.

Let's have a look how the tree examples are being called by a Pure function:

Example 1:

```
f[a_, b_, c_][r_] := a b c^r
f[#1, #2, #3][#4] &[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* 162 *)
```

Example 2:

```
 f[a_, b_, c_,r_] := a b c^r
    f[#1, #2, #3,#4] &[1, 2, 3, 4]
    (*162*)
```

Example 3:

```
 f[{a_, b_, c_},r_] := a b c^r
    f[#1, #2] &[{1, 2, 3}, 4]
    (*162*)
```

In general it is preferable to limit the number of arguments for a function to a minimum necessary. Example 1, even that it works technically is not very readable in the code and I would recommend to avoid it.

Hint:
The corresponding rules processed by the Mathematica kernel can be revealed using DownValues. For example

```
fn[a_, b_, c_, r_] := a+b+c+r
DownValues[fn]
```

(* {HoldPattern[fn[a_, b_, c_, r_]] :> a+b+c+r} *)