# Graphics Function Definition Style (Using SubValues vs. DownValues)

Tags: function-construction, downvalues, subvalues

I am going through some of the items in "Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica, Third Edition".

An example of the style used by these authors is:

```
piriform[a_, b_][t_] := {a (1 + Sin[t]), b Cos[t] (1 + Sin[t])}

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[piriform[1, 1][t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Can someone please explain why they use piriform[a_, b_][t_] as opposed to piriform[a_, b_, t_]?

Is there some advantage to the authors' form over the latter form?

Comment: In the first case (`piriform[a_,b_][t_]`), you define `SubValues` for the symbol `piriform` while in the second case (`piriform[a_,b_,t_]`) you define `DownValues`. BTW, you don't need the `Evaluate` here.

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues/545#545 and this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/define-parameterized-function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The form `f[a_, b_][t_]` allows you to conveniently use `f[a, b]` as if it were a function.  For example, you can [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) it over a list:

```
f[a_, b_][t_] := a^t + b

f[2, 3] /@ {4, 6, 8}
```

> ```
> {19, 67, 259}
> ```

Please see [Define parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/define-parameterized-function/8003#8003) for details about this format and alternatives.  See also [What is the distinction between DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues/127#127) for notes about the specific evaluation of SubValues definitions.

Be aware that it is difficult to use Hold attributes for the additional parameters of a function written this way but one can emulate it to a degree.  See for example:

- [Currying with *Mathematica*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686494/currying-with-mathematica)
- [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121)