# what the meaning of function definition in this form?

Tags: function-construction

In the post [Mathematica code for Bifurcation Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/mathematica-code-for-bifurcation-diagram), I noticed that *Mark McClure* define a function like this:

```
f[a_][x_] := a*x - 1.19 x^3;
```

I wonder its difference from:

```
f[a_,x_]:=a*x - 1.19 x^3;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [(96)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96), [(544)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544); possible duplicate: [(40171)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40171)

Comment: How is this related to Curry[] in 11.3?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your advice. Could you tell me how to close this question by myself, while I want to leave it for my further reference?

Comment: @PureLine I think only users with >= 3000 rep. can cast close votes and mark it as a duplicate.  If you see a "close" button under the question, you might be able to vote to close your own question.  Otherwise, you'll have to wait for community members to cast the votes.

Comment: Or maybe "Community" will do it by magic... :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok! I get it. Thank you.