# What's the difference between f[a_,b_][x_,y_] and f[a_,b_x_,y_]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to find information in reference guide. Didn't find.

Comment: The first syntax are [SubValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues.html). See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40176/85954) for example.

Comment: Look up [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [`CurryApplied`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurryApplied.html).