# How to select specific subvalues from a function definition

Tags: subvalues

Consider:

```
h[1][tag1] = 1;
h[1][tag2] = 2;
h[2][tag1] = 3;
h[2][tag2] = 4;
```

Is there a fast way to obtain downvalues for only h[1], or h[2]? For example

```
DownValues[h[1]]
```

does not work, and neither

```
DownValues[h]
```

(OwnValues gives the same behavior).

Comment: Are these not `SubValues`? Try `SubValues[h]`. Also a quick search for `SubValues` led to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686494/currying-with-mathematica) linked therein that might be of relevance

Comment: great! SubValues[h] works. thanks! But SubValues[h[1]] doesn't. Of course, one can extract these from SubValues[h] but that might be problematic for many subvalues. I still wonder if there is a way to index them directly.

Comment: Yep, I think you'd have to find a good way to extract them from the list of subvalues. I don't trust myself to make up a pattern that is failsafe (hence I am not answering this) but `Cases[SubValues[h], HoldPattern[_[h[1][_]] :> _]]` works here.

Comment: @gpap nice comment, it encouraged me to look further. Note that the `HoldPattern` in your `Cases` gets ignored, and then the `_[]` inside the `HoldPattern` will actually match the `HoldPattern`. If this was intentional to avoid the behaviour of `RuleDelayed` inside cases, well then good job :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Yes, the `HoldPattern` in my `Cases` matching is wrapping the whole rule; it's there so that the rule itself is matched as a pattern. I think (hope) that this is the standard way to match rules. The `HoldPattern` in the subvalues of h is ignored and I've used `_[]` to denote a generic head (that here happens to be `HoldPattern` as well. But I doubt that's the best way you can write this :)

Comment: @gpap it is a bit confusing I think, but I suppose that is hard to avoid. In my answer I made the pattern as specific as possible, as didn't want the confusion with `HoldPattern`, but this comes at the cost of more complex code. Another alternative is `Cases[SubValues[h], Unevaluated[_[_[h[1][___]], _]]]`, where `RuleDelayed` was replaced by a generic head. That is consistent with making `HoldPattern` generic, and another advantage is that we can now use `Unevaluated` rather than `HoldPattern` to avoid evaluation.

Answer (score 6):

#### Method 1: using extra symbols and `DownValues`

Here is a version which will give you the constant time lookup for your `DownValues` of interest, for the price of introducing additional symbols. These symbols however are dealt with in semi-automatic fashion. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[h];
h /: (head:Remove|Clear|ClearAll)[h]:=
    (UpValues[h]={};Remove@@Most[DownValues[h]][[All,2]];head[h]);

h /: HoldPattern[DownValues[arg_h]]:=
    With[{res=arg},
        DownValues[res]/;HoldComplete[res]=!=HoldComplete[arg]
    ];

h[arg_]:= h[arg]=Unique["Temp`h",{Temporary}]
```

Here are the `DownValues` of `h` before assignments:

```
DownValues[h]

(* {HoldPattern[h[arg_]] :> (h[arg] = Unique["Temp`h", {Temporary}])} *)
```

Now we perform the assignments:

```
h[1][tag1] = 1;
h[1][tag2] = 2;
h[2][tag1] = 3;
h[2][tag2] = 4;
```

and now the `DownValues` are:

```
DownValues[h]

(*
  {
    HoldPattern[h[1]] :> Temp`h66, 
    HoldPattern[h[2]] :> Temp`h67, 
    HoldPattern[h[arg_]] :> (h[arg] = Unique["Temp`h", {Temporary}])
  }
*)
```

The memoization is used so that extra symbols are created the first time they are needed.

Now, we also overloaded `DownValues` for `h`, so that you can query:

```
DownValues[h[1]]

(*  {HoldPattern[Temp`h66[tag1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[Temp`h66[tag2]] :> 2} *)
```

so the symbol (`` Temp`h66 `` here) holds specific values for `h[1]`, and the lookup is immediate. You can use things like

```
h[1][tag2]

(* 2 *)
```

just as normal, without thinking about all this mechanics. The only practical change here is that you have another level of indirection, so the lookup time is doubled - but in practice this will in most cases not be the main time sink.

Now, we can see which extra symbols are there:

```
Names["Temp`*"]

(* {"Temp`h66", "Temp`h67"} *)
```

Once you call `Clear`, `ClearAll`, or `Remove` on `h`, those symbols automatically get removed as well, since we overloaded these functions (via `UpValues`):

```
Clear[h]
Names["Temp`*"]

(* {} *)
```

So, management of these "composite" objects is not much harder than if you only had one symbol.

#### Method 2: using `Associations` (V10)

In V10, there is a new object introduced, `Association`, which is an immutable associative array. Using these, one can do without extra symbols, and still have a constant-time lookup for a part of values of interested.

Essentially, you asked about nested hash tables. If we use `Association`-s, then here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[assoc];
assoc = Association[];
assoc /: (assoc[part_][rest__]=val_):=
    Module[{inner=assoc[part]},            
        If[MatchQ[inner,_Missing],inner=<|{}|>];
        inner[rest]=val;
        assoc[part]=inner;
        val
    ];
```

Now, we have:

```
assoc

(* <||> *)

assoc[1][tag1] = 1;
assoc

(* <|1 -> <|tag1 -> 1|>|> *)
```

you can see that the inner association has been automatically created and populated. Now:

```
assoc[1][tag2] = 2;
assoc

(* <|1 -> <|tag1 -> 1, tag2 -> 2|>|>  *)
```

and finally:

```
assoc[2][tag1] = 3;
assoc[2][tag2] = 4;
assoc

(* <|1 -> <|tag1 -> 1, tag2 -> 2|>, 2 -> <|tag1 -> 3, tag2 -> 4|>|> *)
```

You can now query the values corresponding to say, key 1:

```
assoc[1]

(*  <|tag1 -> 1, tag2 -> 2|>  *)
```

The advantage of this scheme is that no management of extra state is necessary.

#### Generalization to any nesting depth

With some extra effort, and perhaps slightly changing the assignment syntax, you can have this work at any level, not just 2. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[defAssoc];
SetAttributes[defAssoc,HoldFirst];
defAssoc[sym_Symbol,new:True|False:True]:=
    (            
        If[new,sym=<|{}|>];
        sym/:(sym[part_,rest__]=val_):=
            set[sym[part,rest],val];
    );

ClearAll[set];
SetAttributes[set,HoldAll];
set[sym_Symbol[part_,rest__],val_]:=
    Module[{inner=sym[part]},            
        defAssoc[inner,MatchQ[inner,_Missing]];
        inner[rest]=val;
        sym[part]=inner;
        val
    ];
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
ClearAll[assoc];
defAssoc[assoc];
assoc

(* <||> *)
```

Now, perform assignments (note a slightly different syntax):

```
assoc[1, tag1] = 1;
assoc[1, tag2] = 2;
assoc[2, tag1] = 3;
assoc[2, tag2] = 4;
assoc

(* <|1 -> <|tag1 -> 1, tag2 -> 2|>, 2 -> <|tag1 -> 3, tag2 -> 4|>|> *)
```

So far, this is the same as before. However, now you can also do:

```
assoc[2, tag3, tag31] = 5
assoc

(* <|1 -> <|tag1 -> 1, tag2 -> 2|>, 2 -> <|tag1 -> 3, tag2 -> 4, tag3 -> <|tag31 -> 5|>|>|> *)
```

and this will work for any depth. You can then query the parts of definitions which you need, add more or modify existing ones, as needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
h[1][tag1] = 1;

h // SubValues
```

gives

> ```
> {HoldPattern[h[1][tag1]] :> 1}
> ```

Note that really `DownValues` don't play a role here. For what it's worth here is my personal opinion. I don't like definitions that generate `SubValues` very much, I avoid them even more than `UpValues`. In this case you can avoid `SubValues` and have `DownValues` instead as follows. `f` plays the role of `h` here.

```
f[1] = g;
g[tag1] = 1;
```

Then

```
f[1][tag1]
```

gives

> 1

You can now inspect/use the definitions by evaluating `DownValues[g]` and `DownValues[f]`.

**If you really want to get the definitions from the SubValues**

This is a modification of gpap's comment.

```
SetAttributes[getDefs, HoldAll];
getDefs[expr_] :=
 Function[
   Null,
   Cases[SubValues[#], 
    Unevaluated[
     Verbatim[RuleDelayed][Verbatim[HoldPattern][expr[___]], _]]]
   ,
   HoldAll
   ] @@ Hold[expr][[All, 0]]
```

Then

```
getDefs[h[1]]
```

gives

> {HoldPattern[h[1][tag1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[h[1][tag2]] :> 2}

**About getDefs**

The code assumes you have a definition like `h[a][b]:=c`, it won't work if you have more brackets.

Symbols can have `OwnValues` and `SubValues` simultaneously (which is something I recommend you to avoid even more). `getDefs` should work correctly even if this is the case. The trick with `Hold[expr][[All,0]]` is used to deal with this case. The code can be made shorter, but then the user has to tell you what the relevant symbol is, even though that can be derived from `expr`.

`Verbatim` was needed twice, once because if `HoldPattern` occurs in the second argument of `MatchQ`, it is ignored. `Verbatim` was needed another time because if an expression with head `RuleDelayed` is the second argument of `Cases`, this means something special (i.e. replace the patterns found).