# How to remove unnecessary brackets in one formula

Tags: string-manipulation

I have some string,like "3+(3*(2+5))", obvious that some brackets are unnecessary. It can write like "3+3*(2+5)", so I try to use Inactive.

```
ToExpression["3+(3*(2+5))",StandardForm,Hold]
    //Inactivate[#,Plus|Times] & // ReleaseHold

ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))",StandardForm,Hold]
    //Inactivate[#,Plus|Times] & // ReleaseHold
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Sometimes it works,but sometimes it does not work.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try converting to InputForm and back to StandardForm.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the head `Inactive[Plus]` etc. does not inherit the `Flat` attribute of `Plus` and `Times`.  One way is to `Flatten` manually:

```
expr = ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))", InputForm, 
     Hold] // Inactivate[#, Plus | Times] & // ReleaseHold;
Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {
    # /. e : Inactive[Plus][__] :> Flatten[e] &,
    # /. e : Inactive[Times][__] :> Flatten[e] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is to get it, by replacing `Inactive[Plus]` etc. by temporary heads with the `Flat` attribute.

```
Module[{p, t},
 SetAttributes[p, Flat];
 SetAttributes[t, Flat];
 ReleaseHold[
   ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))", StandardForm, 
     Hold] /. {Plus -> p, Times -> t}
   ] /. {p -> Inactive[Plus], t -> Inactive[Times]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Related Q&A: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues

Answer (score 1):

```
(ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))",StandardForm,Hold]//Inactivate[#,Plus|Times]&//ReleaseHold)//.{Inactive[Plus][a___,Inactive[Plus][b_,c_],d___]->Inactive[Plus][a,b,c,d],
Inactive[Times][a___,Inactive[Times][b_,c_],d___]->Inactive[Times][a,b,c,d]}
```

and one more way, but it suits only for expressions with reals and integers

```
(ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))", StandardForm, 
    Hold] /. x : _Integer | _Real :> ToString[x]) // ReleaseHold
```

and this one can take into account non standard symbols like named variables

```
(ToExpression["((3+4)+(5+6))+((7-8)*(9*(1*2)))", StandardForm, 
    Hold]/. x : _Integer | _Real | _Symbol?Not@NameQ :> ToString[x] // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: The last one has a useless initial '('