# Generalised Hold pattern for currying

Tags: evaluation, hold

Let `myFun[a_][b_] := myFun[a[b]]` . The `HoldFirst` attribute will prevent evaluation of `a`. Is there any way to prevent evaluation of `b`?

Comment: Something like this was asked a day or two ago or so. Here’s the canonical Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544

Comment: Just making sure you know about [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-language/curried-functions.html).