# What Does this Syntax Mean in Ouput from DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, syntax, variable, arguments

When I run the code

```
DSolve[y*D[f[x, y, z], z] - z*D[f[x, y, z], y] == 0, 
 f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

I get the following output.

[image: output]

I don't understand this syntax. I know `c_1` is a function name, but the `[x][1/2(y^2+z^2)]` throws me off. Does it mean `c_1` is a function of two arguments? Is it indicating some sort of product? How am I to understand output of the form `f[a][b]` in general?

Comment: For whatever reason, Mathematica separates parameters like `x` from the independent variables of the PDE, that is, those with respect to which the dependent variables are differentiated. In the way in mathematics $f_a(x)$ represents a family of functions of $x$ depending on a parameter $a$, so does the Mathematica expression `f[a][x]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$c_1$ is a function that takes $x$ and $\frac{1}{2}(y^2+z^2)$ as its arguments. I do not know why it shows it this way.  In Maple, same solution is shown as $f \left(x , y , z\right) = F1 \left(x , y^{2}+z^{2}\right)$ where $F1$ is same as Mathematica's $c_1$

One can define a function like this

```
foo[x_][y_] := Module[{}, x + y]
```

And call it as

```
foo[x][y]
```

So the answer is just using the above definition for $c_1$.  Not the standard one:

```
 foo[x_,y_] := Module[{}, x + y]
```

but both ofcourse work. The second definition is called using `foo[x,y]` and the first definition using `foo[x][y]`. It is probably a style choice why one is used vs. the other by `DSolve`.

Comment: Is there a difference in use between `foo[x_][y_]` and `foo[x_,y_]`? The second is more common and the one I stick to. The former could conflict with indexed functions of the form `foo[x_][k]` and it seems wiser to stick to that convention. But is there any way they act differently in code?

Comment: @Just The first defines a subvalue of `f`, the second defines a downvalue of `f`. The differences in function definitions are discussion several Q&As, such as [(96)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96), [(544)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544), [(7999)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999). It's not clear to me that this applies to the expression returned by `DSolve`, which is not a function definition. It seems sufficient to observe that the `Head` of `C[1][x][y z]` is `C[1][x]`, and its `Head` is `C[1]`, and finally its head is `C`; and `C` has no definitions.

Comment: One implication is that if you want to substitute a function for `C[1]` in the `DSolve` solution, such as `foo`, it should defined via a subvalue `foo[x_][u_]`, not a downvalue `foo[x_, u_]`.  I sometimes define `foo[x_][u_] := foo[x_, u_]; foo[x_, u_] := <whatever>` to take care of both forms.