# Best practices or hidden drawbacks to define multiple-argument functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, coding-style

I was wondering if there were any important differences or stylistic considerations for deciding between different ways to define functions of multiple variables, e.g.

```
f[ x_, y_ ] := x + y
f[{x_, y_}] := x + y
f[x_][y_]   := x + y
```

Reviewing some of my code, I noticed that I do not follow any one pattern consistently. Does anyone have a principled approach?

Comment: Each makes a certain usage more convenient or less convenient. For instance, do you want to take derivatives? Do you want `f` to have attributes like `HoldAll` or `Listable`?

Comment: Using f[x][y] which is referred as subvalues of f is convenient when using Postfix notation like expression // f[x]. However, it is inconvenient when x has a default value like f[x_:0][y_]:=formula because if you do not want to specify a value for x you have to write expression // f[]. If instead you wrote f[y,x_:]:=formula then you could just write expression // f.

Comment: If the function treats all variables on a similar footing it can be convenient to use f[X_]:=formula where X is a list. This is true as well if you want to specify conditions for X like f[X_] /; VectorQ[X,NumericQ]:= formula

Comment: sorry in my first comment I should have wrote f[y,x_:0] instead of f[y,x_:]

Comment: `f[{x_,y_}]` can be handy for vector-valued functions, so `Nest*` can be applied

Comment: An obvious advantage for `f[{x_,y_}]` is that if you are passing a small list (say a point with coordinates x,y,z). so Instead passing it as single variable say `f[pt_List]` and then having the function do `pt[[1]]` for `x` and `pt[[2]]` for `y` and so on, the function can just use the `x,y,z` names directly. The code becomes much more clear.

Comment: `Nest[Apply@f, {x, y},...]` can be used on vector-valued outputs for `f[x_, y_]`. Likewise `{x, y} // Apply@f`.

Comment: If `f[x][y]` evaluates to an algebraic expression, then `D[f[x][y], x]` works as expected. If `g` is undefined, then `D[g[x][y], x] /. g -> f` does not.

Comment: It seems to me it will be hard to give an answer that addresses all issues. Well, maybe, "I use them all, too. Just use the one that works best in each situation."

Comment: I sometimes use subvalues for functions of the form `f[data][args]`, where data might be some state data, parameter values, method data, metadata, etc. Probably got this idea from exploring the `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate` caverns.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues

Comment: Maybe someone would like to compose an answer? It seems there is plenty of relevant stuff to mention that could be helpful to others. @MichaelE2

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answering your question, but if I wanted to define functions taking the arguments in these forms, I would make the definitions as minimal as possible.  For example

```
f1[x__] := Plus[x]
f2[x_List] := Plus @@ x
f3[x_] := x + # &

{f1[3, 4], f2[{3, 4}], f3[3][4]}
(* {7, 7, 7} *)
```