# Selectively Mapping over elements in a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I am using the following code to easily generate a row of images of all eight planets of our Solar System:

```
Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
  AstronomicalData["Planet"] // Row
```

I like the above code because it is concise and gives nice output.  However, if I wanted to do something similar for the moons in our Solar System, I run into the problem that only some moons have images.  If I run the following line of code, I get a somewhat sloppy output with `Missing Image` errors embedded.

```
Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
  AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"] // Row
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to `Map` over a list of data conditionally?  That is, if an element in a list does not meet a specific condition then skip over it.  Note that I'm looking to avoid an explicit loop with an `If` construct.  I really don't mind using a loop with an `If` statement, but I was curious if there was a concise idiom that anyone could shed some light on.

Comment: This is a beautiful illustration of many ways to solve a problem in Mathematica!

Comment: There is a lot of truly excellent feedback on this page.  I learned something new from each person's answer.  Thank you everyone for contributing.

Comment: Also, thank you rcollyer for cleaning up my post :)

Comment: The more I look at these answers the more I see just how much experience you guys have.  Seriously a dizzying array of different approaches.  I've learned SOO much more looking up the strange code I've seen here than what I originally came here to learn :D  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's an option which only passes moons with images to the Labeled function:

```
Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
  Select[AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"], 
   ImageQ[AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] &] // Row
```

[image]

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Your example uses purely functional programming, gets straight to the point, and avoids any unsightly workarounds.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 15):

This is absurd in how it looks, but in this case I don't think skipping over the missing images is necessary. Instead, we are going to [redefine what `Missing`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/52) means by attaching an [upvalue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/52) to it using [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) (`^:=`), as follows

```
Block[{Missing},
  Labeled[_, _Missing] ^:= Sequence[];
  Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]]
] & /@ AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"] // Row
```

and returns what you expect. `Block` allows you to [temporarily redefine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/52) what a `Symbol` means, and in this case, I set `Missing["NotAvailable"]` to return a [`Sequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html). An empty sequence has the special property that it will truncate a list it is found in, for example

```
{a, b, Sequence[], c}
```

returns

```
{a, b, c}
```

So, by redefining `Missing` to return an empty `Sequence`, the code shortens the list for you.

Also, here's a purely functional approach that does not require accessing the database more than twice: once for the list of the moons and once for the image.

```
labelledMoon[name_String, img_?ImageQ] := Labeled[Text@name, img]
labelledMoon[_, _Missing] := Sequence[]
labelledMoon[#, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
  AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"] // Row
```

This employs the feature of an empty `Sequence` to automatically shorten the list. Here's a self contained version:

```
With[{name=#, img = AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]},
  If[Head[img]=!=Missing, 
     Labeled[Text@name, img],
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]
  ]]& /@  AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"] // Row
```

which gives the same result. Note, this required the use of `Unevaluated` to ensure that the empty `Sequence` was inserted properly into the list.

A functional alternative to `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` is to use a [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html). As
`##&[1,2,3]` returns `Sequence[1,2,3]`, then an empty `Sequence` can be returned via `##&[]`. Here's the shortened version:

```
With[{name=#, img = AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]},
  If[Head[img]=!=Missing, Labeled[Text@name, img], ##&[]]
]& /@  AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"] // Row
```

All 4 versions of the code output:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You will "test" if `Missing["NotAvailable"]` is returned every time anyway. So a "concise" approach is to filter them out at the end:

```
Cases[Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
   AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"], _[_, _Image]] // Row
```

I'd be curious to see a more "concise" piece of code. Alternatively instead of using exact pattern `_[_, _Image]` you could just use `_Image` and specify all levels in expression to search for that pattern:

```
Cases[Labeled[# // Text, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]] & /@ 
   AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"], _Image, Infinity] // Row
```

But this is a few characters longer ;-)

Comment: Or complementarily, `DeleteCases[(* stuff *), _Missing]`...

Comment: Thank you for posting this, Vitaliy. I've learned a lot from your example.  I would say that this answer comes in second place only because it requires more computation than the answer provided by David Skulsky.  Mr. Skulsky's answer avoids running Map on elements unless they meet the criteria.  In your answer all elements are computed and then filtered.  Either way, this is a great answer.  Thank you!

Comment: +1 for Vitaly's answer because his approach only calls AstronomicalData[#,"Image"] once for each moon, whereas my approach calls it twice.

Comment: @J.M. I was rather referring to ` _Missing` part - it won't delete because `Labeled` wrapped around ` _Missing`. You cracked me up with the "idiom" joke  ;)

Comment: Still, the pattern can be changed accordingly. Or, use `DeleteCases[]` before any further processing's done. :) Anyway, at least you got my intent.

Answer (score 14):

In situations like your, where you don't know the number of elements in your result in advance, two functions become very handy: `Reap` and `Sow`. The approach is to `Sow` an element you want in your list deep inside the code and to `Reap` them at the outside.

To get all primes below 11 you can do

```
Reap[Table[If[PrimeQ[i], Sow[i]], {i, 10}]]

(*
  {{Null, 2, 3, Null, 5, Null, 7, Null, Null, Null}, {{2, 3, 5, 7}}}
*)
```

Note that `Reap` gives you two lists, the first one is your original `Table` result which contains `Null` when a number is not prime and the last list contains only the `Sow`ed elements. Therefore, your moons are extracted by

```
Row[Last[Last[Reap[With[{img = AstronomicalData[#, "Image"]},
       If[Head[img] =!= Missing,
        Sow[Labeled[# // Text, img]]]] & /@ 
     AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"]]]]]
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is yet another approach:

```
Cases[
  Thread[ AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon", #]& /@ {"Name", "Image"} ],
  {n_, i_Image} :> Labeled[Text@n, i]
] // Row
```

Answer (score 8):

In version 10, the `GeneralUtilities` context provides a `MapIf` function that does exactly this:

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
MapIf[f, EvenQ, Range@10]
(* {1, f[2], 3, f[4], 5, f[6], 7, f[8], 9, f[10]} *)
```

As with `Map`, `MapIf` can also be used in an operator form with `MapIf[f, test]`.

Answer (score 6):

For shorter lists you can use patterns. For example you want to apply a function only to the even numbers of a list:

```
n = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 8]
```

> ```
> {5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5, 7, 7}
> ```

```
n /. i_?EvenQ -> f[i]
```

> ```
> {5, f[2], 1, f[6], f[8], 5, 7, 7}
> ```

In your case, you would have to replace the `EvenQ` by something like a `HasImageQ`, and `f` by a function that determines how matching entries have to be displayed.

You may also want to have a look at [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html), which is capable of doing a similar thing.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like I'm a year late to this fun filled party, but here's my take:

```
names = AstronomicalData["PlanetaryMoon"];
data = {names, AstronomicalData[#, "Image"] & /@ names};
MapThread[Labeled[Text@#1, #2] &, data] /. Labeled[_, _Missing] -> Sequence[] // Row
```

Comment: For what it's worth you don't need pattern names; `Labeled[_, _Missing]` will work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Ah yes, since I don't refer to them again. Edited to include your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Also, if you are open to funny looking patterns: `DeleteCases[MapThread[Labeled[Text@#, #2] &, data], _~_~_Missing] // Row` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you lost me there, you'll have to explain `_~_~_Missing` to me.

Comment: It's equivalent to `_[_, _Missing]` but in infix form, and without the spacing needed to make that form readable.  I don't recommend it in practice!  For another humorous pattern see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/making-a-symbols-new-definitions-be-tried-before-all-previously-defined-ones#comment7665_2804).  Frightening, isn't it? :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks for explaining. The pattern from the answer you linked is definitely scary :-)