# Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

[My last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/selectively-mapping-over-elements-in-a-list) to the site resulted in several answers that involve using pattern matching in Mathematica, a feature I wasn't very familiar with at the time.  I am currently reading [Mathematica Navigator](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123741646) and am picking up a bit on patterns.  Very powerful stuff!  My question may not have a definite answer, but I am curious.

When performing pattern matching there are two ways that I see that seem to provide very similar functionality.  First there are `PatternTest`s, such as the following:

```
(* Replace all items in list that fall in the interval [0, 1] with 1
 * using a PatternTest *)
{1, 2, 3, 0.4, 0} /. x_?(0 <= # <= 1 &) -> 1
```

The `PatternTest` being the true/false test within the parenthesis after the question mark.  Alternatively there are `Condition`s.  Here I accomplish the same as the above but with a `Condition`:

```
(* Replace all items in list that fall in the interval [0, 1] with 1
 * using a Condition *)
{1, 2, 3, 0.4, 0} /. x_ /; 0 <= x <= 1 -> 1
```

Here the `Condition` is the same true/false test after the `/;` operator.  I [mostly] understand how these work, but I am curious why both of these exist.  I can see why one method would be preferable in some conditions while the other would be preferable in other conditions.  For instance, a `PatternTest` seems to be preferable in situations where a simple test is involved:

```
f[x_Integer?EvenQ] := x+1
```

And a `Condition` seems preferable when a more complex condition is required:

```
f[x_Integer /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]] := x+1
```

Is this the only justification for having both operators?  Are there additional details behind-the-scenes that should influence my decision of which one to use or is it purely a matter of preference?

As a bonus, are there any old timers that can give the history of these two methods of pattern matching?  I.e, which of these two operators was implemented first in Mathematica?

**EDIT**

From the answers that have been posted so far, it appears that `Condition`s have a much wider and more general use case than `PatternTest`s.  I wonder if it would be correct to say that the use cases for `PatternTest` are a *subset* of the use cases for `Condition`, and hence `PatternTest`s are merely a syntactic sugar of sorts and is more or less redundant (although still helpful and preferable is some circumstances.)  This still begs the question of why `PatternTest`s exist other than as a convenience.  This is where a historian might be able to shine some light.  If `PatternTest`s were first implemented in Mathematica, then adding `Condition`s in a later version would add flexibility to the language.  However, if the `Condition` shorthand syntax was first implemented, then was the `PatternTest` syntax later implemented as a shorthand convenience operator?

Comment: Regarding your edit, according to the help files both PatternTest and Condition were introduced in version one.

Comment: I know nothing of the internals, but it is often quicker to write using `PatternTest` than `Condition`. Although, for complex conditions, `Condition` is superior.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 That is helpful to know!  Then this may be chalked up to the whims of the developers during those early stages of development.  Although I do still wonder if both syntactic *operators* were added in version one, or just the functions...

Comment: I updated my answer with a difference between the two that I don't believe has been covered yet.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I usually consider PatternTest as local to a specific pattern such as `x_Integer?Positive` and Condition as more general, often involving multiple patterns, e.g.:

```
f[x_, y_] /; x+y < 10 := x*y
```

An aspect of PatternTest that is different from Condition is that it is automatically applied to each element of a sequence, whereas Condition applies to the whole.  A pattern such as `__?EvenQ` means a sequences of arguments all of which pass `EvenQ`.  Consider:

```
f2[x__?EvenQ] := . . .
```

This is awkward with Condition:

```
f1[x__] /; (And @@ EvenQ /@ {x}) := . . .
```

Furthermore the naive method above does not short-circuit on a failure therefore it will be inefficient.  This could be fixed but it will be even more clumsy.

Then consider the converse:

```
f3[x__] /; Plus[x] == 7 := . . .
```

To do this using `PatternTest` we would need to apply it to the entire expression `f3[x__]`, complicating its form and risking unwanted evaluation or recursion.  (Counterexample: see my proposed solution to [Quick way to use conditioned patterns when defining multi-argument function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52057/quick-way-to-use-conditioned-patterns-when-defining-multi-argument-function/52058#52058) for where I feel that `PatternTest` *is* the best way to proceed.)

There is one rather obscure (at least to me) yet very important [use of Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html#123) that extends this generality.

> **lhs := Module[{vars}, rhs /; test]** allows local variables to be shared
>   between test and rhs. You can use the same construction with Block and
>   With.

This is quite unusual in *Mathematica's* patterns and assignments.  It allows execution of code as part of the definition, *then* testing by a condition based on the result.  If the condition fails, the pattern matcher then moves on to search for other matches.  The evaluation that occurred can produce side effects but otherwise *Mathematica* behaves as though the entire pattern (`lhs := rhs` assignment) did not match.

One elegant use of this functionality is the [Trott-Strzebonski method for In-Place Evaluation](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html).

---

[Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) wrote, and encouraged me to include here:

> One other thing I want to mention is that with `PatternTest`, it is
>   easier to inadvertently leak evaluation, while in `Condition` avoiding
>   that is usually just a matter of inserting `Unevaluated` in a proper
>   place. I discussed this topic to some extent [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-optional-arguments-and-options/1579#1579)
>
> Finally, there are some syntactic differences which are good to keep
>   in mind, for example precedence-related issues like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/why-doesnt-patterntest-work-with-composition).

---

Rojo stated:

> Another consequence of this shows when you want to store a pattern in
>   a variable, or inject it with a With. ... Can't do that with Condition
>   unless you want all the instances of the pattern in each definition to
>   be the same.

As a rather contrived counter-example one can use `Unique` symbols in a pattern constructor:

```
pat[] := Pattern[#, _] /; # > 4 & @ Unique[]

f[a : pat[], b : pat[]] := {a, b}

f[5, 6]
```

> {5, 6}

Of course it is *better* to use PatternTest for this, but I think it is useful to show that it can be done.

Comment: Ok, deleted mine.

Comment: @Leonid is this a handicap because you are bored with being completely unchallenged for the top of the scoreboard?

Comment: No, I just noticed that the question was well-answered by Rob and you for the  most part, so there was not that much to add. As to the scoreboard, I am pretty sure that you and Szabolcs will be ahead of me quite soon, which is just fine.

Comment: @Leonid only if you accept a position as Professor of Mathematica and have no more time for the site. :-)

Comment: lol :) I will probably have less time for it in the coming weeks, but I don't think this will be a big deal.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I have edited my question in hopes of being more clear in what I am looking for in an answer.  Would you care to give it a go?

Comment: @Alfred I'd love to, but alas have no time right now, since I have to leave  soon. When I return, and if no one else answers, I'll surely give it a shot.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Excellent exposition of some important differences between the two.  +1

Comment: @AlfredFazio, while I'd like the accept (and another silver badge) this is the superior answer, I believe, since it covers a number of good points which I didn't rather succinctly.

Comment: @rcollyer there should a moderator-granted "gentleman" badge for such behavior, although in fairness it couldn't be given for such behavior toward a moderator.

Comment: I believe in giving credit where it is due. If I find another answer is superior, I'll encourage the OP to accept that one regardless of the effort that I put into mine. While I could wish all viable answers were accepted, the most complete should win.

Answer (score 32):

`Condition` has three forms in which it can be used in defining a function:

1. `f[x_Integer /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]] := x+1`,
2. `f[x_Integer] /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x] := x+1`, and
3. `f[x_Integer] := x+1 /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]`

which are interpreted slightly differently by Mathematica. For instance, the first form results in the `Pattern`, `x_Integer`, being interpreted as

```
Condition[Pattern[x,Blank[Integer]], And[EvenQ[x],Positive[x]]]
```

or, in short hand

```
Condition[ x_Integer, EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]]
```

The second form looks like,

```
Condition[f[x_Integer], EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]] := x + 1
```

The third form is interpreted as,

```
f[x_Integer] := Condition[ x + 1, EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]]
```

They all give identical results. The timings reveal a slightly different tale:

```
f0[x_Integer?(And[EvenQ[#], Positive[#]] &)] := x + 1
f1[x_Integer /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]] := x + 1
f2[x_Integer] /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x] := x + 1
f3[x_Integer] := x + 1 /; EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]

rnds = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 1000000];

Timing[f0 /@ rnds;]
Timing[f1 /@ rnds;]
Timing[f2 /@ rnds;]
Timing[f3 /@ rnds;]
(*
{1.75124, Null}
{1.41897, Null}
{1.4107, Null}
{2.17659, Null}
*)
```

The timings for `f1` and `f2` do exhibit some volatility, and occasionally exceed the timing for `f0`, but, for the most part, are consistently faster than `PatternTest`. The timing for `f3` is always slower, much slower.

**Edit**: However, some caution needs to be applied here. With a single condition, such as `EvenQ`, the results for `PatternTest` are on par with the results for the first two forms of `Condition`. Again, the third form is slower, and usually over twice as slow.

**Edit - 2**: The increase in speed I was seeing when using `Function` was [illusory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/52). The results for simple conditions still holds, though. The more complex conditions using functions is as slow as `f3`.

```
(* Note the parantheses around Function *)
f4[x_Integer?(Function[{x}, EvenQ[x]&&Positive[x]])] := x + 1

fcn1[x_] := EvenQ[x] && Positive[x]
f5[x_Integer?fcn1] := x + 1

fcn2 = EvenQ[#] && Positive[#] &
f5[x_Integer?fcn2] := x + 1

(* Timings, respecively
{2.37899, Null}
{1.92366, Null}
{1.86119, Null}
*)
```

Condition does have the advantage of clarity as you can use the variable names within it directly. An advantage that is not easily overcome.

Comment: Very instructive comparatives!

Comment: Good post except that `f4` is missing a bracket and parentheses, and furthermore I don't think it works the way you think it does.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard fixed about 2 hours ago. I read Leonid's post, too, so I'm a little ashamed that I fell into the same trap.

Answer (score 18):

Adding 1c to the good answers already...

In `Condition` you need named patterns, and that brings issues when you create composite patterns because all patterns with the same name need to be the same expression.

So let's say you want `f` to match with a sequence of even arguments. The following works, as noted by Mr.Wizard

```
f[x__?EvenQ]:=3
```

But it wouldn't have worked something like

```
f[(x_/;EvenQ[x])..]:=3
```

This matches only when all the even numbers are the same number.

Another consequence of this shows when you want to store a pattern in a variable, or inject it with a `With`. So, you could easily do something like this

```
With[{myPatt=(_?(EvenQ[#]&&somecomplicatedstuff[#]&))},

f[myPatt, x_Integer]:=blabla;
g[r[myPatt, myPatt]]:=bloblo;
]
```

Can't do that with `Condition` unless you want all the instances of the pattern in each definition to be the same.

Comment: Never too late to join the party :)  I believe that Mr.Wizard more or less covered the case of `PatternSequence`s in his answer.  However, your example of storing a `PatternTest` for later use is very interesting.  This seems like it could be especially useful in instances of meta programming.  +1

Comment: @AlfredFazio yeah, I saw afterwards that he had covered that, so I edited. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent point about assigning patterns to symbols, which I do often for full function definitions. +1

Comment: Rojo, I added a rather horribly contrived counter-example to my answer that may be of interest.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, true, interesting and contrived, hehe. Fills the context with `$` symbols but works... Can't be done with `With` though

Comment: I accept the challenge. :-)  `With[{pat := Pattern[#, _] /; # > 4 & @ Unique[]}, f[a : pat, b : pat] ]` Success!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, haha, that's cheating, doesn't work if f is HoldAll

Comment: Okay I just realized why you'd be using With in the first place; granted I don't know how to make it work in that circumstance without *more* contrivance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose it should work, with both versions of `With`, since it doesn't need to be evaluated to become the pattern we want

Answer (score 6):

I tried several variations and here are the two fastest ways I can find to do a simple task.

```
In:=  data = RandomReal[{-0.2,1}, 10^7];
      Timing[ Count[ data, x_/;Positive[x] ];]
```

> `Out= {5.897,Null}`

```
In:=  data = RandomReal[{-0.2,1}, 10^7];
      Timing[ Count[ data, _?Positive ];]
```

> `Out= {5.164,Null}`

**Notice  `_?Positive`  is the fastest and most concise.**

My intent above was only to compare `?Positive`  with  `x_ /; Positive[x]`. 
Afterwards I realized a faster way to count the positive numbers in a long list is the following.

```
In:=  data=RandomReal[{-0.2,1},10^7];  
      Timing[Count[Positive[data],True];]  

Out=  {0.998,Null}
```

Next we see the timing differences of `Condition` and `PatternTest` are different for a more complicated example.

```
In:= data = RandomInteger[{-100,100},10^7];  
    Timing[Count[data,x_?(Function[n,And[Positive[n],EvenQ[n]]])];]  

Out=  {20.109,Null}  


In:=  data = RandomInteger[{-100,100},10^7];  
    Timing[ Count[data, x_/;And[Positive[x],EvenQ[x]] ];]  

Out=  {10.717,Null}  


In:= data = RandomInteger[{-100,100},10^7];  
    test[n_] = And[Positive[n],EvenQ[n]];  
    Timing[ Count[data, x_?test[x]]; ]  

Out= {0.546,Null}  


In:= data = RandomInteger[{-100,100},10^7];  
    Timing[ Count[data, x_?(And[Positive[#],EvenQ[#]])&]; ]  

Out= {0.515,Null}
```

---

Next I illustrate a point Mr. Wizard mentioned without an example above.
Use of `/;` (`Condition`) is very helpful here, and `PatternTest` can't be used in its place.

```
In:=  OnlyLargeFactors[factored_]:= 10^15 < Min[Part[factored,All,1]];
      foo[n_Integer]:= With[{factors=FactorInteger[n]}, 
          factors/;OnlyLargeFactors[factors]
       ]
```

The definition of `foo` isn't used in the first example because the integer has small factors.

```
In:= foo[10^40+543]
```

> `Out= foo[10000000000000000000000000000000000000543]`

In the next example the definition is used because the integer has only factors larger than $10^{15}$.  If not for the use of `Condition` we would have to evaluate `FactorInteger` twice and that can take a long time.

```
In:= foo[100000000000000109301303000000000001424179]
```

> `Out= {{1000000000000001093,1},{100000000000000000001303,1}}`

I am using Mathematica version 7, and I the last example works if I use `Module` instead of `With`.
However, it doesn't work if I use `Block`.

Comment: This code is broken.  `test[n_] = And[Positive[n],EvenQ[n]];` evaluates RHS to `False`, furthermore `x_?test[x]` is misapplied.  The next example is also broken because you left the `&` outside the `( )`.