# Match patterns on list of Strings

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
data={"AB","CD","AF"};
```

Now I would like to delete all String from `data` which starts with "A".

Result: `{"CD"}`

Comment: May be somthing like `DeleteDuplicates[data,First@Characters[#]=="A"]` but abviously this is not working.

Comment: It is well known that Wolfram Language favors immutability, therefore deletion functionality can be meant in many ways, e.g. selecting strings that match a pattern, cases of string patterns, picking string patterns. But in all cases, including the DeleteCases, a copy of the data list with those patterns that do not match these cases is returned. Therefore deletion here is not meant in a mutable way like it often happens with other programming languages, e.g. remove an element from a Python list. This may be too obvious for mature users of the language, but for a newcomer it is frustrating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this using `DeleteCases`, but you can still use the `Select` function:

```
Select[data, StringTake[#, 1] != "A" &]
```

which has the desired result.

**Edit** Actually, you can also use `DeleteCases` like this:

```
DeleteCases[data, _?(StringTake[#, 1] == "A" &)]
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is another one:

```
DeleteCases[data, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "A*"] &)]
```

Comment: The OP should take careful note of the parentheses around `StringMatchQ[#, "A*"]&` as the parser for `PatternTest` (`?`) is aggressive. Without it, the parser comes up with `Function[PatternTest[Blank[], StringMatchQ][Slot[1], "A*"]]` as opposed to the correct form `PatternTest[Blank[], Function[StringMatchQ[Slot[1], "A*"]]]`.

Comment: I don't want to post it as a new answer, as there are already quite a handful, and it is very similar to the one above but uses `Condition` instead of `PatternTest`: `DeleteCases[data, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "A*"]]`. And of course there are a million ways to write the same pattern differently.

Comment: Thank you @IstvánZachar, that made me search on the differences between PatternTest and Condition. I do not think these are covered from WL Documentation. But I found this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching) enlightening !

Answer (score 7):

```
 Pick[data, StringMatchQ[#, "A*"] & /@ data, False]
 (* => {"CD"} *)
```

EDIT: As noted in YvesKlett's comment, since `StringMatchQ` threads over its first argument, we can also use

```
 Pick[data, StringMatchQ[data, "A*"], False]
```

or

```
 Pick[#, StringMatchQ[#, "A*"], False]&@data
```

Comment: The disadvantage I can see is the double pass over `data`. But, it works, so +1.

Comment: `Pick[data, StringMatchQ[data, "A*"], False]` should work as well, since it accepts a list of strings as first argument... saves on wear and tear on your keyboard ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett, right! Thank you.

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks for the vote. For large lists, `Pick` "usually" more than compensates for the double-pass overhead associated with creation of the selector array, provided, of course, the selector array is carefully constructed.

Answer (score 6):

### Synopsis

It is not really an answer but a synopsis on answers of this post. I thought it will be useful for newcomers of WL patterns like me, so I thought to share it with you ;-)

Answers can be categorized in terms of the function and the pattern test. This is the list of patterns I have taken. I have also included negated forms that are used with Select.

```
strQ1   =StringTake[#,1]=="A"&;
strQ1Neg=StringTake[#,1] !="A" &;

strQ2   =StringStartsQ["A"];
strQ2Neg=Not@*StringStartsQ["A"];

strQ3   =StringMatchQ[#,"A*"]&;
strQ3Neg=Not@*strQ3;

strQ4    =StringMatchQ[#,"A"~~__]&;
strQ4Neg =StringMatchQ[#,Except["A"]~~__]&;
strQ4Neg2=StringFreeQ[#,"A"~~__]&;

strQ5    =StringMatchQ[#,"A"~~WordCharacter]&;
strQ5Neg =StringMatchQ[#,Except["A"]~~WordCharacter]&;
strQ5Neg2=StringFreeQ[#,"A"~~WordCharacter]&;
```

These can be used with the following WL functions, I use operational forms, wherever possible, and postfix notation to highlight the transformation.

#### DeleteCases

```
data // DeleteCases[_?strQ1]
data // DeleteCases[_?strQ2]
data // DeleteCases[_?strQ3]
data // DeleteCases[_?strQ4]
data // DeleteCases[_?strQ5]
```

#### Cases

```
data // Cases[Except[_?strQ1]]    
data // Cases[Except[_?strQ2]]    
data // Cases[Except[_?strQ3]]    
data // Cases[Except[_?strQ4]]    
data // Cases[Except[_?strQ5]]
```

#### Pick

```
data // Pick[#,strQ1/@#,False]&
data // Pick[#,strQ2@#,False]&
data // Pick[#,strQ3@#,False]&
data // Pick[#,strQ4@#,False]&
data // Pick[#,strQ5@#,False]&
```

#### Select

```
data // Select[strQ1Neg]
data // Select[strQ2Neg]
data // Select[strQ3Neg]
data // Select[strQ4Neg]
data // Select[strQ4Neg2]
data // Select[strQ5Neg]
data // Select[strQ5Neg2]
```

### Output

> {"CD"}

### Benchmarking

I have decided to benchmark those answers above to find which one is the fastest. This is the procedure I have followed.

#### Timing

Each computation is measured with Timing that is repeated 100 times. Then I am taking the Mean of the results, e.g.

```
q1DeleteCases = Table[data // DeleteCases[_?strQ1] // Timing // First, {100}] // Mean
```

All values are converted to milliseconds, my $TimeUnit is 1/100. These are all the results per category.

```
{timingCases, timingDeleteCases, timingPick, timingSelect}
```

> {{133.151,677.71,94.879,314.711,310.773},{115.781,674.823,84.6535,296.377,287.192},{94.8139,40.2126,8.64794,18.9432,18.7907},{89.8032,716.253,105.113,263.977,149.96,262.98,149.862}}

#### Barchart Plotting

```
patternTestsQ1toQ5={"q1:StringTake", "q2:StringStartsQ", "q3:StringMatchQ[#,\"A*\"]", "q4:StringMatchQ[#,\"A\"~~__]", "q5:StringMatchQ[#,\"A\"~~WordCharacter"};

patternTestsSelect = {"q1Neg", "q2Neg", "q3Neg", "q4Neg", "q4Neg2", "q5Neg", "q5Neg2"};

{
BarChart[timingDeleteCases,
ChartElementFunction->"GlassRectangle",ChartStyle->"Pastel",
ChartLegends->patternTestsQ1toQ5,AxesLabel->{"DeleteCases","ms"},TargetUnits->"ms",ChartLabels->Placed[timingDeleteCases,Top],ImageSize->Large],
BarChart[timingCases,
ChartElementFunction->"GlassRectangle",ChartStyle->"Pastel",
ChartLegends->patternTestsQ1toQ5,AxesLabel->{"Cases","ms"},TargetUnits->"ms",ChartLabels->Placed[timingCases,Top],ImageSize->Large],
BarChart[timingPick,
ChartElementFunction->"GlassRectangle",ChartStyle->"Pastel",
ChartLegends->patternTestsQ1toQ5,AxesLabel->{"Pick","ms"},TargetUnits->"ms",ChartLabels->Placed[timingPick,Top],ImageSize->Large],
BarChart[timingSelect,
ChartElementFunction->"GlassRectangle",ChartStyle->"Pastel",
ChartLegends->patternTestsSelect,AxesLabel->{"Select","ms"},TargetUnits->"ms",ChartLabels->Placed[timingSelect,Top],ImageSize->Large]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### BarChart Comparison

Comparison of the first three BarCharts, columns are grouped by pattern test with a function chart legend and timing data labels at the top of each bar.

[image]

One can notice that timing for DeleteCases is slightly faster than Cases and there is a significant improvement on the speed of calculations for pattern matching that is based on the Pick function.

#### System Information

```
{$OperatingSystem,$ProcessorCount,$ProcessorType, MemoryInUse[],$Version}
```

> {Unix,2,x86-64,257092208,10.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 8, 2015)}

#### Fastest Answer

All Pick answers are much faster compared to other solutions, but the one with this PatternTest q3:StringMatchQ[#,"A*"] is significantly faster. I am leaving  justification to the experienced user of WL.

Comment: (+1) Just in case I point you to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32063/280) for short discussion on the difference between `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming`. String-matching functions internally use the PCRE library, and I can't to say for sure whether the CPU time spent in this library is included in `Timing` or not.

Answer (score 5):

Another method using `Select` but with what I find to be a more obvious notation.

```
Select[d, StringMatchQ[#, Except["A"] ~~ __] &]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another solution that has not been mentioned using `Select` and `StringFreeQ`

```
Select[{"AB", "CD", "AF"}, StringFreeQ[#, "A" ~~ ___] &]
(* {"CD"} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

A possibly dangerous version that works for your example:

```
data = {"AB", "CD", "AF"};
Flatten[StringCases[data, Except["A"] ~~ __]]
```

> ```
> {"CD"}
> ```

uh, and adding variety to the `Pick` faction:

```
Pick[data, Thread[StringTake[data, 1] != "A"]]
```

> ```
> {"CD"}
> ```

Comment: +1 for posting the dangerous version. I came up with that one as well, and thought, "I don't like the look of this"

Comment: Sometimes you gotta take a risk ;-)

Comment: Can you elucidate why the first one is dangerous?

Comment: I didn't test but you might get tangled up with other string configurations more easily?

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[data, Except[_?(StringMatchQ[#, "A*"] &)]]
```

> ```
> {"CD"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which may add flexibility if one is working with more complicated strings or required patterns

```
Select[ data, StringMatchQ[#, "A" ~~ WordCharacter] & ]
```

If, for example, one would want to select from `data2` those strings which start with a numeric digit and which have "C" as a second digit:

```
data2 = {"AB1", "C2D", "3AF", "A41", "5CD", "FG6"};
Select[ data2, StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ~~ "C" ~~ WordCharacter] & ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect fit for the newish (10.1) [`StringStartsQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringStartsQ.html) function and "curried" operators:

```
Select[data, Not @* StringStartsQ["A"]]
(* {"CD"} *)
```

**EDIT**. Also, here's a silly approach using `Pick`'s optional "pattern" argument:

```
Pick[data, Characters[data], {Except["A"], __String}]
(* {"CD"} *)
```

The redundant-looking `String` qualifier is there because of the [rather weird way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119223/531) that `Pick` uses pattern arguments.

Comment: Slight modification: `data // Pick[#, # // StringStartsQ[#, "A"] &, False] &` I was not aware of `StringStartsQ` until I saw your answer