# Why is StringMatchQ["IP1", "IP"] returning False?

Tags: string-manipulation

Maybe there is a knot in my head, but I would expect that

```
StringMatchQ["IP1", "IP"]
```

should return `True` (which it does not) just as

```
StringFreeQ["IP1", "IP"]
```

returns `False` (which it does). What am I missing?

Comment: If `StringFreeQ` is to strings as `FreeQ` is to expressions, then `StringMatchQ` is to strings as `MatchQ`, and not as `MemberQ`, is to expressions

Comment: Related: [(8945)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8945/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`StringMatchQ` tests the pattern, and "IP1" doesn't match the pattern "IP", it does match the pattern `___~~"IP"~~___`, but that's a different pattern! Similarly you could write your pattern as `StringMatchQ["IP1", "IP*"]`

`StringFreeQ` however doesn't just test the entire string, it tests every substring, so in effect the `___~~pattern~~___` is added by the function itself to your pattern.

Comment: `StringMatchQ["IP1", "*IP*"]` is the more appropriate equivalent to `StringMatchQ["IP1", ___~~"IP"~~___]`, no?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I find it also odd that `StringMatchQ["IP1", RegularExpression["IP"]]` is `False`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I was referring to his pattern in particular, however i suppose that wasn't clearly stated.

Comment: @KarstenW. `RegularExpression["IP"]` is an exact "pattern", so you are asking if your string is equal to "IP", in other languages the pattern would be "^IP$". If you want to match anything containing IP, you have to specify the "anything containing" part of the pattern. `StringMatchQ["IP1", RegularExpression[".*IP.*"]]` is True.

Comment: @Karsten, in short, `StringMatchQ[]` doesn't implicitly insert wildcards; if you want wildcards, you need to explicitly put them in.

Answer (score 3):

If you like to think in negatives and avoid regular expressions:

```
!StringFreeQ["IP1", "IP"]
```

> True