# Using Except with strings

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering

Suppose that I have the following sample list, called `list`:

```
list = {"bBb", "aAa", "aaa"};
```

Now suppose I want to select the elements that do not contain the string `"A"`.  One way to do this is to use `Select` with `StringMatchQ`:

```
Select[list, ! StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___] &]
```

> {"bBb", "aaa"}

(See, for example, [this old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/specifying-string-patterns-in-deletecases).)

But, instead of selecting the elements which do *not* contain `"A"`, is it possible to use `Select` with `StringMatchQ`, but this time selecting all patterns *except* those that match the pattern `___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___`.  My thought is to use `Except`:

```
Select[list, StringMatchQ[#, Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]] &]
```

> {}
>
> StringExpression::invld: Element `Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]`
>   is not a valid string or pattern element in
>   `StringExpression[Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]]`

But I get the error message above.  So I looked in the [documentation for `StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringMatchQ.html).  It has the following three general syntax forms:

```
StringMatchQ["string", patt]
StringMatchQ["string", RegularExpression["regex"]]
StringMatchQ[{s1, s2, ...}, p]
```

Thinking about the first form, `StringMatchQ` takes a pattern as its second argument.  I know that `___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___` is a pattern, but is `Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]` a pattern?  According to the [documentation for `Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Except.html), it is.  The next question is, is `Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]` a *string* pattern?  According to the error message above, it would seem not.  (Also, apparently `StringMatchQ` takes only *string* patterns as its second argument -- which, of course, is logical.)

***So, my overall question is,*** why does `Select[list, StringMatchQ[#, Except[___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]] &]` give an error?

Comment: I've found that `Except` is generally buggy with strings, which is why I always avoid it (with strings).  For instance, compare: `StringMatchQ["a", Except["b"]]` and `StringMatchQ["a", Except["bb"]]`

Comment: @rm-rf The `StringExpression` doc says: `Except[p] -  any character except ones matching p` IMHO implying that p can only be a character in this context and not a string. Behavior is therefore documented and not a bug.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ah, good point. I forgot that `StringMatchQ` internally calls `StringExpression` on the second argument. That also explains OP's error then. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When applied to string patterns `Except` only seems to work for string patterns that represent classes of characters or for string patterns that represent positions in strings, e.g.:

```
Except[{"A" | "B"}]
Except[WordCharacter]
Except[StartOfLine]
```

If you apply `Except` to an arbitrary String pattern (i.e., the head is `StringExpression`), the resulting expression does not seem to be a workable string expression. The documentation does not make this explicitly clear.

An alternate solution is to use `StringFreeQ` instead of `StringMatchQ` with `Except`:

```
Select[list, StringFreeQ[#, ___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___] &]
```

Also note that if the list is really large, using `Pick` in combination with the listable form of `StringFreeQ` is an order of a magnitude faster:

```
Pick[list, StringFreeQ[list, ___ ~~ "A" ~~ ___]]
```

Answer (score 11):

The `StringExpression` doc says: `Except[p]: any character except ones matching p`. This seems to imply that `Except[p]` can only stand for a *single* character in this context and not a string.

Comment: WRI is the master of implicit documentation...

Comment: @Christ, this hasn't been fixed since 2013?

Comment: It's 2022, I'm trying to use Except in the same way and it's still not fixed lol

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to sakra's answer, here's one way of using `Except` with *whole* strings as arguments.
Suppose you have two lists:

```
countries = {"PitcairnIslands", "Jordan", "Serbia", "Greece", "Zimbabwe"};
continents = {"Oceania", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe", "Africa"};
```

We want to `Pick` those countries, which are *not* in Europe.
A first – obvious – attempt fails:

```
Pick[countries, continents, Except["Europe"]]
```

yields

```
{PitcairnIslands, Jordan, Serbia, Greece, Zimbabwe}
```

The trick is, you have to add a "parent class of pattern" as a second argument in Except. This works:

```
In[121]:= Pick[countries, continents, Except["Europe", _String]]
```

gives the desired output.

```
{"PitcairnIslands", "Jordan", "Zimbabwe"}
```

I admit this is somewhat counterintuitive for such `Except` constructs.
Hope that helps a little!