# Alternative to Except in StringExpression when using StringMatchQ

Tags: string-manipulation

According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39527/9048) and [the documentation for StringExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html), `Except` can only be used in `StringExpression` for classes of characters or positions in strings. The referenced answer suggests using StringFreeQ in place of StringMatchQ. However, sometimes, this is not possible, if the pattern is one of many being passed to a function, like in the following situation

```
patt1 = WordCharacter..;
patt2 = "pattern";
patt3 = (*Some complicated StringExpression*);
... (*more patterns*)
pattn = (*Everything except patt3*)

f[patt_, str_] := If[StringMatchQ[str, patt], (*stuff*), (*other stuff*)]
```

One possibility is to use

```
pattn = x: __ /; !StringMatchQ[x, patt3]
```

This seems repetitive and it could get verbose if repeated, but isn't too bad. However, my intuition is that there should be a better way. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

This code turns `f[ ___ , Except[ _RegularExpression ] , ___ ]` into `!f[ ___ , RegularExpression, ___ ]` if `f` begins with `String`. It would work for `StringFreeQ` and `StringMatchQ` but you would have to adjust it for others such as `StringCases`.

```
Unprotect[Except];
Except /:
 symbol_[head___, Verbatim[Except][re_RegularExpression], tail___] /; 
  StringMatchQ[SymbolName[symbol], "String" ~~ __] := ! symbol[head, re, tail]
Protect[Except];

regex = RegularExpression@"[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alnum:]]+\\.[[:alnum:]]{2,}";

StringMatchQ["test@example.com", regex]
```

> True

```
StringMatchQ["test@example.com", Except@regex]
```

> False

```
StringMatchQ["not.an.email", Except@regex]
```

> True

Comment: Very interesting ! Bending Mathematica to my will (like a good lawyer the jury): How can I bring it back to standard behaviour later?

Comment: Does this (with minor alteration) support StringExpression as well?

Comment: @Daniel Yup. Right now it will catch any symbol beginning with String. You could make it behave differently depending on the exact symbol, or more specific patterns.

Comment: @eldo Have a look at `Information[ Except ]` in this example; you will see the extra definitions at the bottom. Since it is a system symbol, you can do `Unprotect[Except];ClearAll[Except];Protect[Except];` to restore base definitions.

Comment: @Daniel Alternatively, you could attach this rule to your function (here `f`) (instead of `String...`). So you could specify: any time `RegularExpression` is passed to `f` then do ...

Comment: @mfvonh - Thank you very much - (I didn't know that one can run a "ClearAll" over a system-function).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

```
Clear[patt1, patt2]
patt1 := "__~~WordCharacter"
patt2 := "pattern"

ClearAll@f
f[patt_ /; patt == patt1, str_] := StringMatchQ[str, ToExpression@patt]
f[patt_ /; patt == patt2, str_] := Not@StringFreeQ[str, patt]
f[patt_, str_] := str (* or whatever you want *)
```

Comment: That's a possible solution, but it require at least two function definitions, and requires adding every new pattern to one or the other.

Comment: @Daniel -Yes, that's right. An alternative would be to define "f" only once and then use a "Switch"-statement. But some of the experts here prefer the "verbose" solution. Also, you don't need to define "patt1" & "patt2" beforehand. You could directly write: "f[patt_ /; patt == "pattern", str_] := ..."