# Error when combining Except, "*" and an additional character

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 5 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

Anyone knows why

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"1", "2"}]]

StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"*"}]]

StringMatchQ["x", {"1", "*"}]   (* without Except *)
```

all work as expected, but

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"1", "*"}]]
```

throws the following error:

```
StringExpression::invld: Element Except[{1,*}] is not a valid string 
   or pattern element in StringExpression[Except[{1,*}]]. >>
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39527/57

Comment: Doesn't [your own answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39526/121) imply that this usage is invalid?

Comment: @mr.wizard that answer implies that the pattern (Except [p]) can only *stand* for a single character, not that the pattern element itself (p) must be a single character. The first example seems to support this.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I have read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39526/121) but I think that even if we accept that *implicit documentation statement* we still have a couple of bugs here...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that `StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"*"}]]` works as expected as well as `StringMatchQ["x", Except["*"]]`:

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"*"}]]
StringMatchQ["x", Except["*"]]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

The string pattern `"*"` is an *abbreviated string pattern* consisted from the only metacharacter `*` which corresponds to **zero or more characters** according to the first point under the "Details and Options" section of [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html). So by the definition the pattern `Except["*"]` shouldn't give a match at all because it means negation of literally everything. Also for matching verbatim `"*"` one must escape this metacharacter with double backslash `"\\*"` (the reference is the same). So current behavior is a bug.

Note also that escaping with single backslash is meant for *Mathematica*'s internal metacharacters like `<` and `>` (and obviously for more common `n`, `t` and `r` etc. but with another counting by `StringLength`) as described in [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00462.html) answer by John Fultz:

> The modern Mathematica notebook format (introduced in 1996) was always
>   made to be interpreted properly as a Mathematica expression should you
>   call `Get[]` on it from the kernel.  So this syntax was standardized,
>   and is still used today. Now, the kernel simply ignores the `\<` `\>`
>   delimiters as you can see below:
>
> ```
> In[1]:== StringLength["\<x\>"]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Out[1]== 1
> > ```

The following demonstrates a possible bug (for the string `"\*"` length must be `2` because `*` isn't an internal metacharacter of *Mathematica* and it needs not be escaped inside of an ordinary string):

```
StringLength["*"]
StringLength["\*"]
```

> ```
> 1
>
> 1
> ```

```
StringLength["\x"]
```

> Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \x.

```
2
```

---

The following is a set of examples of the expected behavior (observed with version 10.4.1):

```
StringMatchQ["", "*"]
StringMatchQ["", Except["*"]]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["xy", {"*"}]
StringMatchQ["xy", "*"]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["*", Except[{"*"}]]
StringMatchQ["*", Except["*"]]
StringMatchQ["xy", Except["*"]]
```

> ```
> False
>
> False
>
> False
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["x", "@"]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["x", {"\\*"}]
StringMatchQ["x", "\\*"]    
StringMatchQ["*", "\\*"]
```

> ```
> False
>
> False
>
> True
> ```

The following is a set of examples of wrong behavior of `Except` with metacharacters:

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"\\*"}]] (* metacharacter is correctly escaped *)
StringMatchQ["x", Except["\\*"]] (* metacharacter is correctly escaped *)
```

> StringExpression::invld: Element Except[{\*}] is not a valid string or
>   pattern element in Except[{\*}]. >>
>
> ```
> StringMatchQ["x", Except[{"\\*"}]]
> ```
>
> StringExpression::invld: Element Except[\*] is not a valid string or
>   pattern element in Except[\*]. >>
>
> ```
> StringMatchQ["x", Except["\\*"]]
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except["\*"]] (* metacharacter is wrongly escaped *)
StringMatchQ["*", Except["\*"]] (* metacharacter is wrongly escaped *)
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

```
StringMatchQ["x", Except["@"]]
```

> StringExpression::invld: Element Except[@] is not a valid string or
>   pattern element in Except[@]. >>
>
> ```
> StringMatchQ["x", Except["@"]]
> ```

And here is an example of wrong (but consistent) behavior of `StringMatchQ` both with `Except` and without it:

```
StringMatchQ["\*", Except["\*"]] (* metacharacter is wrongly escaped *)
StringMatchQ["\*", "\*"] (* metacharacter is wrongly escaped *)
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

In addition:

```
StringMatchQ["*", Except["\*"]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

#### Update

I've found an old MathGroup [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/nz4Iona_XeM/uHWKJZBmHRYJ) on this topic from where I learned that `StringCases` and `StringPosition` don't support abbreviated string patterns, and that `Verbatim` forces `StringMatchQ` to match two strings literally: `StringMatchQ["\\*", Verbatim["\\*"]]` returns `True`.

Comment: It's a bit long ago, so I don't recall what made me write "work as expected". Perhaps I was just looking at the generation of an error message. Anyway, it indeed looks like there is a bug in Mathematica's treatment of meta-characters. Nice treatment of the issue (+1).