# What are "\<" and "\>" delimiters in box expressions?

Tags: syntax, cells, display, boxes, input-forms

If I enter a string (say, `"abc"`) in a cell, and then switch to box representation (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or menu item `Cell ► Show Expression`), I see the following:

```
Cell[BoxData["\"\<abc\>\""], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.662918813714031*^9, 3.6629188530623317`*^9}}]
```

I understand everything in this expression except the delimiters `\<` and `\>`. They look like escape sequences (e.g. `\\`, `\"`) or like symbols used in [string representation of boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html) (e.g. `\(`, `\!`, `\*`, etc), but I could not find their description anywhere. I experimented a little, and it looks they are ignored within strings (for example `StringLength["\<"]` evaluates to `0`) and rejected as an incorrect input elsewhere.

**What do `\<` and `\>` mean inside of a string? For what purpose they are automatically added into the low-level representation of a cell? What are their use cases?**

---

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"
> ```

Comment: `BoxData["\"\<a\>\""] === BoxData["\"a\""]`

Comment: It was usefull until version 5.2. It is documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-2.8.7)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that John Fultz (Wolfram) has said or written something about the "\<". It was something like he didn't know any more the origin of this, or what was the utility. It has surprised me. I can't retrieve this information Stack Exchange Answer ?, Comments ? Somewhere else ? Wolfram Conference ?

Comment: Just curious if you are using *Mathematica* to automatically create notebooks with [`GenerateDocument`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateDocument.html) or [Low-Level Notebook Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookProgramming.html); since the internal mark-up isn't needed in these cases.

Comment: I think the limiters "\<" and "\>" for a string are relicts from the beginning of Mathematica. I remember having studied them a very long time ago, in Mathematica 1 and/or 2, and that they had to do with the box language. But this box language seems to be undocumented at the moment. I would highly appreciate if someone could refresh my memory.

Comment: `"\<" // InputForm` results simply `""`. I think `\<` and `\>` are invalid escape forms of letters and are plainly dropped when parsing the string.

Comment: We can produce this form using `Subscript["x","y"]` and looking at the cell expression.  The quotes are important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undocumented Backslash-LessThan operator in strings?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112550/undocumented-backslash-lessthan-operator-in-strings)

Comment: Shouldn't the newer one be a duplicate of the older one? Or perhaps they should be merged?

Comment: My answer for this (older) question contains some additional information about significance of these delimiters in newer versions of _Mathematica_.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am in favor of a merge, putting all answers in one place.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Now I see your point. Sorry for the incorrect edit from me. You could incorporate your comment into the answer in order to emphasize its main point.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree they should be merged. (AFAIK, there is no formal method of community review of such a proposal.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [andre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5467/andre)'s comment (where [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-2.8.7) is provided), I now see the effect of those delimiters (I tested it in *Mathematica* 11 and also some earlier versions). When I add 2 newlines to the box representation of the cell:

```
Cell[BoxData["\"\<a

bc\>\""], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.662918813714031*^9, 3.6629188530623317`*^9}}]
```

and switch back using `Shift+Ctrl+E`, then the cell look like this:

```
"a

bc"
```

But if I remove those delimiters:

```
Cell[BoxData["\"a

bc\""], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.662918813714031*^9, 3.6629188530623317`*^9}}]
```

and switch back, then the cell looks like this:

```
"a  bc"
```

It seems that the purpose of `\<`,`\>` is to delimit ranges within string literals in raw box representations of cells where newlines should be exactly preserved. It looks like they only have effect in that context and are ignored in normal input in newer versions of *Mathematica*. The legacy documentation suggests that in *Mathematica* 5 they were significant in all string literals.

---

*Update:* I found an old discussion on this topic:
[[1]](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00428.html),[[2]](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00462.html),[[3]](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00483.html).

Comment: Yes that's right. On Mathematica 5, when you wrote a string on several lines (in normal editing), all the carriage-return were removed, except if the string began with "\< and ended with \>". Nowodays, \< and \> are unecessary (in normal editing).

Comment: Thanks for the links to the information I was looking for !

Answer (score 22):

This syntax was deprecated in the version 6.0 era. According to the [legacy documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.2.3),

[image]

For example, in version 5.2, the following strings are interpreted differently

```
string1 = "first line
  second line"

string2 = "\<first line
  second line\>"
```

[image]

Comment: These delimiters are still significant in string literals in box representations of cells (toggled by `Shift+Ctrl+E`) in newer versions of _Mathematica_ (in particular in _Mathematica_ 11), but lost significance in regular string literals. See [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105094/7288).

Comment: ilian, how would you feel about Merging this question with [(105018)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105018/121)?  That action would move this answer to that Q&A.  You would lose the Accept, unless Vladimir moves the Accept to your answer, but this would keep multiple answers in one place rather than spread between different questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree of course. Actually my answer is not as good and I wouldn't have posted it if I had known of Vladimir's earlier answer at the time.

Answer (score 10):

#### Summary of the all available information

In the hoarier days space-like characters (spaces, newlines, tabs) inside strings were interpreted on input in an odd way: for example [single newlines followed by spaces or tabs were converted to a single space](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112601/280). The `\<\>` syntax was introduced as a way to avoid this: between `\<` and `\>` the space-like characters are interpreted literally with the only exception to line-ending backslash whish escapes the newline. This syntax was standardized in the modern *Mathematica* notebook format (introduced in 1996).

The kernel simply ignores the `\<\>` delimiters on input and also when you `Get` or `Import` a notebook file:

```
FullForm@"\<1\n2\>"
```

> ```
> "1\n2"
> ```

```
"\<\>" // StringLength
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Note that FrontEnd doesn't remove them on normal input:

```
"\<\>";
InString[-1]
```

> ```
> "RowBox[{\"\\\"\\\\<\\\\>\\\"\", \";\"}]"
> ```

Starting from version 6 the behavior of strings *on normal input* was changed and the `\<\>` syntax is [no longer needed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112601/280) for preserving space-like characters. But for direct editing of the low-level box representation of cells in the [special cell editing mode of the FrontEnd](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html) (which is toggled by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) it is still necessary as [Vladimir showed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105094/280). These delimiters aren't needed however when you programmatically work with the low-level representation (and the kernel simply removes them anyway!).

These delimiters are also added automatically when you `Export` as `"NB"`, but not added when you `Export` as `"Package"`:

```
StringCases[ExportString["1\n2", "NB"], "Cell[" ~~ Shortest@__ ~~ "\"Input\"]"] // First //
  ImportString[#, "Text"] &
```

> Cell["\<\
>   
>   1
>   
>   2\
>   
>   \>", "Input"]

```
ExportString["1\n2", "Package"]
```

> (* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
>
> "1\n2"

Despite this a Notebook exported as a `"Package"` can be [correctly opened](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115403/280) or imported as `"NB"` preserving space-like characters:

```
nb = ImportString[ExportString["1\n2", "NB"], "NB"];
ImportString[ExportString[nb, "Package"], "NB"] === nb
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
NotebookPut[nb];
```

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Further elaboration

Let us consider the example given by John Fultz (please copy the code exactly as written!):

```
CellPrint@Cell["abc\
         d"]
```

> ```
> abc         d
> ```

It is easy to check that there are 9 spaces between `abc` and `d` in the printed cell (and so are before `d` in the code). But the newline and the backslash are absent because the backslash at the end of line simply escapes the newline.

After pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> we can see the code of the printed cell:

```
Cell["abc         d",
 GeneratedCell->True,
 CellAutoOverwrite->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{3.680677305471143*^9}]
```

Now let us add a space after the backslash (it isn't visible, but it is there!):

```
CellPrint@Cell["abc\ 
         d"]
```

> ```
> abc 
>           d
> ```

Now we got our newline but the backslash is absent (the next space is present). I think that the absence of the backslash can be related to the series of bugs I discuss in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118405/280). The code of the printed cell:

```
Cell["\<\
abc 
         d\
\>",
 GeneratedCell->True,
 CellAutoOverwrite->True,
 CellChangeTimes->{3.6806776850508537`*^9}]
```

Note that similar things happen when we write `\n` instead of entering the newline:

```
CellPrint@Cell["abc\\n         d"]
CellPrint@Cell["abc\ \n         d"]
```

> ```
> abc\n         d
>
> abc 
>           d
> ```

In the first case here the newline character `\n` is escaped by the backslash and is present in the output literally. In the second case the backslash is absent again but the space at the first line is preserved.

---

#### An old discussion on MathGroup

A closely related (but not identical) question was asked by user kj and answered by John Fultz in the official newsgroup in 2010, so I'll cite here both the question and the answer completely:

[The question](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00428.html):

> When I examine the source code of *Mathematica* notebooks, I often see
>   `Cell` objects whose first argument is preceded by
>
> ```
> "\<\
> ```
>
> and followed by
>
> ```
> \
> \>"
> ```
>
> E.g.
>
> ```
> Cell["\<\
> Yet another undocumented item.\
> \>", "Text"...
> ```
>
> What do these delimiters mean?  And how do they differ from the
>   `TextData` symbol?  (The latter is also undocumented, but at least
>   I've seen "cameo appearances" of it in the documentation.)
>
> TIA!
>   
>   ~kj

[The answer](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00462.html):

> `Cell[_String]` is equivalent to `Cell[TextData[{_String}]]` as far as the
>   front end is concerned.  The former is just an abbreviation of the
>   latter syntax, which is necessarily used when the contents are more
>   complex (e.g., contain styles or buttons).
>
> The `\<\>` business dates back to a hoarier day (in my opinion) in the
>   design of strings in *Mathematica*.  Once upon a time, *Mathematica* had
>   an odd interpretation of newlines which I probably made more sense in
>   the days of 80 character terminal usage.  You'll have to forgive
>   me...my memory is fuzzy here, and I don't have an old *Mathematica* text
>   to double-check this from my current location...but I believe the
>   issue was something like this...
>
> ```
> "abc\
>          d"
> ```
>
> ...with the newlines and spaces as shown, being equivalent to "abc d"
>   (with just the single space).  The `\<\>` business forced everything
>   inside the string to really be interpreted literally, with backslash
>   at the end of a line meaning to simply escape the newline, and do
>   nothing special to leading spaces.  Since the *Mathematica* notebook
>   format generally wraps at about 70 characters, the non-literal
>   interpretation would have made the representation of more than 70
>   consecutive spaces difficult.
>
> The modern *Mathematica* notebook format (introduced in 1996) was always
>   made to be interpreted properly as a *Mathematica* expression should you
>   call `Get[]` on it from the kernel.  So this syntax was standardized,
>   and is still used today. Now, the kernel simply ignores the `\<\>`
>   delimiters as you can see below:
>
> ```
> In[1]:== StringLength["\<x\>"]
>
> Out[1]== 1
> ```
>
> Sincerely,
>
> John Fultz 
>   
>   jfultz at wolfram.com 
>   
>   User Interface Group 
>   
>   Wolfram Research, Inc.

Comment: Alexey, how would you feel about me Merging this question with [(105018)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105018/121)?  That would move this answer to that Q&A.  You would lose the Accept but probably gain visibility for the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually I'm against this but I think reasonable merging this question with [(112550)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112550/280) where we have authoritative answer by ilian. The reason is to have all information in one place; the accepted answer in (105018) doesn't add anything to these answers.

Comment: Hm... I also [asked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112550/undocumented-backslash-lessthan-operator-in-strings#comment336775_112601) ilian about merging.  I think the community would best be served by having all three answers in the same place.  Do you disagree?  If not is there any reason to have them all under 112550 rather than 105018?  Typically we favor older questions unless the newer one is far better written, and that does not seem to be the case here?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree that we can merge all three questions. To my taste, this current question is the most clear and is general enough to have all answers under it. I have one question: what will happen with comments under the questions after merging?

Comment: All comments would be moved to the master question as well.  I hadn't actually considered that in this case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After reading again the [(105094)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105094/280) answer and checking I see that it raises a good point, so I take my words back about it. But I still think that the current question is the most clear and hence is preferable as the master question.

Comment: Alexey, given that ilian agrees with the merge (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112550/undocumented-backslash-lessthan-operator-in-strings#comment336834_112601 ), I would (still) like to make 105018 the master.  It could be edited to include the more concise form of this question as well.  I do not think it should *only* include that short form as I see this question as lacking context (where did `\<` and `\>` come from?).  Would this be a satisfying resolution for you or still problematic?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, I agree.

Comment: With your agreement, the merge is completed.  Do you wish to edit this question now?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have edited the question. BTW, it looks like most of the comments under merged questions are lost. They weren't very valuable but nevertheless...

Comment: Thank you.  Unless I am imagining things the comments were not lost but instead moved here, to this master Q&A.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right, sorry for wrong alert: I just have found here the comment which I remember but wasn't able to find earlier (what made me thinking it was lost with others).