# How to get "one Cell - one line" code format inside of NB files?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, conversion, parsing

The `PageWidth` option controls the way the `Cell`'s content is displayed, not the manner it's written in a `.nb` file. I wish to get a "one `Cell` - one line" representation (i.e., with no line breaking, a sort of `PageWidth -> Infinity` for the file). Is it possible?

This question arises from the necessity of ransacking in a large stack of notebooks by means of a strings search tool.

Comment: Interesting question.  I wish I had an answer.

Comment: Hello ! An alternative could be to import the .nb file as plain text, replace `"\\\n" -> ""` and then perform the search. Do you think that it's trustworthy ? A direct search by means of regular expressions looks much more frightening ...

Comment: Frankly I am not in the habit of reading Notebook code directly so I cannot recall if there are traps for using that simple replacement.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to force the FrontEnd to write the .NB files with `PageWidth->Infinity`. Even if you would be able to do this, your old Notebooks still won't be searchable without re-saving them with the new option. So the correct approach to your problem is to solve it on the level of your *string search tool* without changing the default behavior of the FrontEnd.

Comment: Theoretically the **Wolfram Notebook Indexer** should help with this, but it's only theoretically...

Comment: An alternative is to use *Mathematica* for searching instead of your *strings search tool*. It should be much easier and much more fail-safe approach than writing your own parser of .NB files using regular expressions.

Comment: I suggest you to start from `Import["ExampleData/document.nb", {"Cells", All}]` if you wish to follow the *Mathematica* route for searching. It returns the list of the `Cell`s not in the order in which they are present in the file (what is incorrect from my point of view), but at least it gives them as WL expressions which are convenient for searching.

Comment: Potentially related: [Searching with Workbench](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/notebook/search.html).

Comment: Thanks for the replies ! The use of `Import[fileIn,"Text"]` looks good indeed, but when it comes to regular expressions I still don't go much further than basics. Please, can you point to a source for a reg exp or an algorithm to detect matching square brackets delimitng a Cell ? The command `Import["ExampleData/document.nb", {"Cells", All}]` gives me an error `Import::noelem: "The Import element \"\!\(\"Cell\"\)\" is not present when importing as "NB `; may be it's because I'm using M. 8.0.1 ?

Comment: With *Mathematica* version 8 the command `Import["ExampleData/document.nb", {"Cells", All}]` doesn't work and you should instead use `Import["ExampleData/document.nb", "Notebook"]` what may be even more convenient (depending on your actual goals).

Comment: Related: "[Searching a phrase in all *.nb files](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115337/280)."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For producing a NB file without the line breaks you can `Get` it as a `Notebook` expression, then `Export` it with `PageWidth -> Infinity` as `"Package"` (other possible options does not work correctly: `Export` ignores `PageWidth -> Infinity` when exporting as `"NB"` and corrupts the code when exporting as `"Text"`):

```
Export["document.nb", Get["ExampleData/document.nb"], "Package", 
 PageWidth -> Infinity, "Comments" -> None]
```

This method is safe. *Mathematica* directly opens the generated file as a valid Notebook identical to the original Notebook. The only significant difference is that non-printable ASCII characters (excepting `\b\t\n\r\f`) are written "as is" when exporting as `"Package"`, but in `FullForm` when exporting as `"NB"` (this difference doesn't affect the actual contents of the file when the latter is opened by the FrontEnd).

If you really need the "one `Cell` - one line" formatting you can simply add a line break before each `Cell[` in the obtained string:

```
Export["document.nb", 
 StringReplace[
  ExportString[Get["ExampleData/document.nb"], "Package", PageWidth -> Infinity, 
   "Comments" -> None], c : "Cell[" :> "\n" <> c], "Text"]
```

A special note: this will affect all `Cell`s including the [Inline `Cell`s](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/frontendobject/CreateInlineCell.html) (what may be undesirable but is safe). But the above code isn't safe in the sense that if your file contains textual strings with verbatim `Cell[`, they will also be modified. You can avoid this corruption by replacing the `Head` `Cell` in the `Notebook` expression with your own *uniquely named* `Head` before exporting:

```
Export["document.nb", 
 StringReplace[
  ExportString[Get["ExampleData/document.nb"] /. Cell -> $$$MyUniqueCellHead$$$, 
   "Package", PageWidth -> Infinity, "Comments" -> None], 
  "$$$MyUniqueCellHead$$$" -> "\nCell"], "Text"]
```

You can ensure that your `Head` is really unique by appending a random number to it:

```
With[{uniqName = "$$$MyUniqueCellHead$$$" <> ToString[RandomInteger[{10^8, 10^10}]]},
 Export["document.nb", 
  StringReplace[
   ExportString[Get["ExampleData/document.nb"] /. Cell -> Symbol[uniqName], "Package", 
    PageWidth -> Infinity, "Comments" -> None], uniqName -> "\nCell"], "Text"]]
```

This method is based on the well-documented and widely used functionality and hence should work reliably.

Here is how the obtained file looks in Notepad with word wrapping turned off:

[image: screenshot]

---

04/19/2022 **IMPORTANT UPDATE**

In the recent versions of *Mathematica* (I tested 12.3.1 and 13.0.1) the `Export[..., "Package"]`/`Put` compatibility is partially broken for the `"NB"` format. The problem is that `Export` as `"Package"` and `Put` write `Pattern[sym,obj]` as `sym:obj` instead of `Pattern[sym,obj]` as it was in earlier versions. The syntax `sym:obj` is recognized by the FrontEnd as a *syntax error* when it opens a file as Notebook. I consider this as a bug. As a workaround, we can "protect" the `Pattern` head like we do above for `Cell`:

```
With[{uniqCellHeadName = 
   "$$$MyUniqueCellHead$$$" <> ToString[RandomInteger[{10^8, 10^10}]], 
  uniqPatternHeadName = 
   "$$$MyUniquePatternHead$$$" <> ToString[RandomInteger[{10^8, 10^10}]]}, 
 Export["document.nb", 
  StringReplace[
   ExportString[
    Get["ExampleData/document.nb"] /. {Cell -> Symbol[uniqCellHeadName], 
      Pattern -> Symbol[uniqPatternHeadName]}, "Package", PageWidth -> Infinity, 
    "Comments" -> None], {uniqCellHeadName -> "\nCell", 
    uniqPatternHeadName -> "Pattern"}], "Text"]]
```

Comment: Related WC thread: "[Version control of Mathematica notebooks to include it in git repositories](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2513633)".

Comment: I just discovered that in the WFR is available [`ResourceFunction["SaveReadableNotebook"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SaveReadableNotebook) which at first glance looks like a more generic and advanced approach to the problem than the above.