# Searching a phrase in all *.nb files

Tags: notebooks, string-manipulation, files-and-directories, searching

I have so many `*.nb` files in a folder. In one of them I have written a phrase, unfortunately I cannot remember that file. I am searching about it and the file in which I have written. Is there any way to search to `Find` a proposed phrase or word? I have used `Find` but it just work in an opened file not all files in the folder!

Comment: See the examples in [`CreateSearchIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateSearchIndex.html) -- they exactly for the use case you have.

Comment: On OS X Mathematica integrates with Spotlight (the OS's search system).  It's possible to simply search for the phrase with the file manager.  I don't know if this also work on Windows (there's a good chance it does).

Comment: @Anton Does it explicitly support notebooks or are you relying on the fact that notebooks are just big semi-human-readable expressions anyway?  Just curious.

Comment: @Szabolcs the latter. :) I have to say at some point in order to do expression search within notebooks I experimented with converting them all to text (or PDF's) and then making the search.

Comment: in the olden days one used to `grep pattern *.nb` in the terminal, in case you are in a unix machine.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa Right. Or in emacs.

Comment: I am using Windows and I have used `TextSearch`. Albeit after Anton's comment. It is so helping

Comment: See [How to Search for Text Inside of Any File Using Windows Search](http://www.howtogeek.com/99406/how-to-search-for-text-inside-of-any-file-using-windows-search/) and [Tools to search for strings inside files without indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317944/tools-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-without-indexing)

Comment: In windows, open your CMD in current directory, type `findstr /spin "word" *.nb`. This will search recursively from current directory and all its subdirectory

Comment: This was trivial with the explorer of  Windows XP. Under Windows 7, it is a nightmare. I have spend more than 10 hours on it. It is such a mess that I can't say today if I have found a definitive solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way to search from within mathematica:

```
notebooks = Quiet@FileNames["*.nb", NotebookDirectory[], 2];
Monitor[Select[
   Table[{nb, 
     StringJoin@Select[ StringSplit[Import[nb, "Plaintext"], "\n"] ,
        ((If[#, Print["match on:", nb]]; #) &@
             StringMatchQ[#, "*NIntegrate*"]) &, 5]},
                {nb,notebooks}], #[[2]] != "" &], {nb}] // Grid[#, Alignment -> {Left, Top}, Dividers -> All] &
```

This is painfully slow, but it does just search and show only the plain text of the notebook.

Comment: Neat (+1). When I tried your code the results look better with `Grid` than with `MatrixForm` so I changed your answer...

Comment: Unfortunately **NBImport.exe** (which actually imports NB files under the hood) returns `$Failed` when trying to import a NB file with non-ASCII file path.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov good point.  worth noting also the failure can be "silent" in the above code (It returns the string `$Failed` but does not actually generate an error ).  I ran the above on my entire system and only got faied on 2 notebooks that also report errors simply opening in the front end (But I don't use non-ascii paths)

Comment: An alternative to `Import[nb, "Plaintext"]` is new in 10.1 `NotebookImport[nb, _ -> "Text"]`.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of additional solutions. The first, with `FindList`, is probably the simplest and quickest.

### Using FindList

```
searchDir = "<NB dir>";

fnames = FileNames["*.nb", searchDir, 2];
Length@fnames

sres = {#, FindList[#, {"curve"}, WordSearch -> False]} & /@ fnames;
sres = Select[sres, Length[#[[2]]] > 0 &];
Grid[sres, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

See the options of [`FindList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindList.html).

### Using CreateSearchIndex

```
searchDir = "<NB dir>";

index = CreateSearchIndex[searchDir]

sobjs = TextSearch[index, {"curve", "regression"}]

sres = MapThread[{#1, 
     StringCases[#2, "curve" ~~ (Except["\n"] ...) ~~ "regression", 
      IgnoreCase -> True]} &,
   {Through[sobjs["Location"]], Through[sobjs["Plaintext"]]}];

Grid[sres, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

See the signature of [`TextSearch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html) -- it allows complicated "and", "or", "except" searches.

This solution seems to be fairly slow.

Answer (score 7):

**Note: the following method isn't robust. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115499/280) answer of mine for a robust solution.**

---

Here is an approach which does not rely on the **NBImport.exe** (which actually performs importing of the NB files as `"Plaintext"` under the hood) and performs all the operations in the Kernel only. Currently **NBImport.exe** contains a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/280) due to which it returns `$Failed` when have to import a NB file with non-ASCII file path.

The weak side of the following method is that it relies upon the ability of `MakeExpression` to convert a low-level `Notebook` expression into the high-level `DocumentNotebook` what it doesn't always able to do even for correct NB files (and this ability is [not guaranteed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/toexpression-and-toboxes-arent-inverses-of-each-other/112491?noredirect=1#comment341377_112491) by the developers in general). This conversion is necessary because `ToString` doesn't accept raw boxes as the low-level representation of a WL expression (even wrapping the raw boxes by `RawBoxes` is simply ignored).

The simple function presented below currently fails in many situations but demonstrates the idea.

Here is a function which `Get`s the contents of a NB file as `Notebook` expression, then extracts all the `Cell`s as the actual WL expressions wrapped by `HoldComplete`, converts them into strings and checks whether they contain specified string pattern or not:

```
findInNBFile[NBFilePath_String, stringPattern_] := 
  Module[{expr = MakeExpression[Get[NBFilePath], StandardForm], cellExprPos, foundPos},
   cellExprPos = Replace[Position[expr, ExpressionCell | TextCell], 0 -> 1, {2}];
   foundPos = 
    Flatten@Position[
      StringFreeQ[
       StringTake[ToString /@ Extract[expr, cellExprPos, HoldComplete], {14, -2}], 
       stringPattern], False];
   If[foundPos =!= {}, 
    Grid[Join[{{Row[{"Found \"", stringPattern, "\" in file \"", NBFilePath, "\""}], 
        SpanFromLeft}, {"Cell #", "The Cell"}}, 
      Transpose[{foundPos, Extract[expr, Most /@ cellExprPos[[foundPos]], HoldForm]}]], 
     Frame -> All], {NBFilePath, False}]
   ];
```

It can be used as follows:

```
findInNBFile["ExampleData/document.nb", "abcde"]
```

> [image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution written in the spirit of the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115377/280) by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) but NOT relying upon the [buggy **NBImport.exe**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115400/280) executable. Instead it uses FrontEnd for converting Notebooks into plain text using the findings described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115488/280):

```
findInNBFile::cntconv = "Failed to extract plain text from `1`";
findInNBFile[NBFilePath_String, stringPattern_, resPerFile_Integer: 5] := 
 Module[{NB, NBText, NBlines, matches},
  NB = Get[NBFilePath];
  NB = Notebook[First@NB, 
    Join[FilterRules[List @@ Rest[NB], 
      Except[DynamicUpdating | NotebookDynamicExpression]], {DynamicUpdating -> False, 
       NotebookDynamicExpression -> Null}]];
  NBText = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NB, "PlainText"]];
  If[TrueQ[Head[NBText] === List && Head[First@NBText] === String],
   NBlines = StringSplit[First@NBText, "\n"];
   matches = Flatten@Position[StringMatchQ[NBlines, stringPattern], True];
   If[matches =!= {}, Print[Length[matches], " matches on: ", NBFilePath]];
   {NBFilePath, Length[matches], 
    StringJoin@
     If[Length[matches] > resPerFile, NBlines[[Take[matches, resPerFile]]], 
      NBlines[[matches]]]},
   Message[findInNBFile::cntconv, NBFilePath];
   {NBFilePath, $Failed,}]
  ]
```

For example, let us find all Tutorials containing the word `NIntegrate`. Listing of the all Tutorials:

```
notebooks = 
  FileNames["*.nb", 
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", "System",
      "Tutorials"}]];
Length[notebooks]
Total[FileByteCount /@ notebooks]/1024.^2
```

> ```
> 715
>
> 215.841
> ```

Searching (I won't post here the output except to the timings):

```
startTime = AbsoluteTime[];

Monitor[Select[Table[findInNBFile[nb, "*NIntegrate*"], {nb, notebooks}], 
   TrueQ[#[[2]] > 0] &], {nb}] // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> {Left, Top}, Dividers -> All] &

DateString[AbsoluteTime[] - startTime, {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}]
```

> "00:08:11"

We have successfully processed 715 Notebooks of total size 215 Mb in 8 minutes. Not so bad...

Note that the above function extracts text also from textual elements inside of output, even from the saved (cached) versions of `Dynamic` expressions. For example in the "Views.nb" Tutorial Notebook the word "Afghanistan" is present only inside of the cached `Dynamic` output for the second example under the ["SlideView" section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Views.html#947630944). Let us try to find it:

```
findInNBFile[
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", "System", 
   "Tutorials", "Views.nb"}], "*Afghanistan*"]
```

> 2 matches on: C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.4\Documentation\English\System\Tutorials\Views.nb
>
> ```
> {"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\Documentation\\English\\System\\Tutorials\\Views.nb",
> 2,
> "BoxData[Afghanistan]
> BoxData[Afghanistan]
> "}
> ```

Found!

Answer (score 1):

A Unix style text search works best for me. The following search is a timed search over all the .nb files on a 2017 iMac 4GHz Quad Core i7 with 32 GB. The timed find / grep command is:

find . -name \*.nb -exec grep -iH nintegrate {} \;  71.11s user 3.30s system 97% cpu 1:16.48 total

1:16 wall clock time. The files searched were in a multiple directory structure with 2.9 GBytes of files over 1949 .nb files. The directory tree had 1974 subdirectories.

The Mathematica code above that starts with "notebooks = Quiet" required 3:52 wall clock time (mm:ss) or about 3 times slower.