# Improved Documentation Search By Actual Content

Tags: documentation, searching

Now by default Mathematica documentation searches keywords section in the Options version of the notebook and the actual text of the notebook.  For example here is a snippet from `Print`.

```
"keywords" -> {
  "display",
  "type",
  "Write",
  "printf",
  "putc",
  "putchar"...
  }
```

Now if I search for `Print x+y, then print a+b:` you get `Print` as the top result.  I don't care so much how the results are populated but is annoying to me that the preview of `Print` simply displays `Print[expr] prints expr as output.`

Is there an easish way to make the documentation display the actual snippet that matches the result?  Google does this very well by putting the similar text in bold.

If this is to broad vote to close or leave comments.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115337/280