# What does the pair "\<" and "\>" in a string do?

Tags: string-manipulation, syntax, display, boxes, input-forms

What do `\<` and `\>` mean inside of a string?

```
SubscriptBox["\<\"x\"\>", "\<\"y\"\>"] // DisplayForm
```

> $\text{x}_\text{y}$

The tutorials [String Representation of Boxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConvertingBetweenStringsBoxesAndExpressions.html) and [Converting between Strings, Boxes and Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConvertingBetweenStringsBoxesAndExpressions.html) don't seem to have any reference to this.

Comment: [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105018/5467)