# The character sequence "\\. d" triggers line break in strings

Tags: bugs, formatting, templates

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persists through 11.0.0**

<sup>Bug isn't present in version 5.2</sup>

---

**Update:** Sjoerd pointed out that this happens with any string and it is not related to StringForm. Just evaluate `"foo bar \\. daz."`. Or type `"\\. d` directly, and watch the cursor jump after typing the d.

---

I found the weirdest problem with messages and `StringForm`.

This works fine:

[image]

But let's change that `b` to a `d` now:

[image]

*What is going on?*  Where did that line break come from?

It turns out that the problem is actually in StringForm.

```
StringForm["foo bar \\. daz."]
```

[image]

It's a bug and it's there at least in 8.0.4-10.4.1.  But can anyone offer an explanation about the cause?  Removing either the backslash (remember that `\\` denotes a single backslash) or the `.` or changing the `d` to something else prevents the problem.  It doesn't matter if I use a capital or lowercase d.

Comment: The string "foo bar \\. daz." itself, executed in its own cell, has the same problem. It does not seem to be related to StringForm or Message specifically.

Comment: It's even weirder: In an empty cell type "\. d" (including the double quote character) and the cursor moves to the next line the moment you press the 'd' button.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks!  I didn't notice that!  In a terminal it doesn't happen.  This suggests that it may be related to the string representation of boxes.

Comment: Note also that "\\." and "\." yield the same characters. Clearly a bug and perhaps related to [the bug Alexey reported earlier this week](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118405/57).

Comment: I can confirm this bug also exists in v8.04

Comment: Note BTW that "\." is used to initiate a hexadecimal character code. "\. d" doing something like the above may be related to the carriage return being ASCII 13 and d the hexadecimal notation for 13. Apparently, space+d are similar to 0d.

Comment: @Sjoerd 13 (or `0D`) is CR.  10 (or `0A`) is LF.  Using `a` instead of `d` also triggers the problem.  `b` does not.  This confirms your theory.

Comment: Yep, the bug is, I guess, that the first "\" doesn't escape the second one.

Comment: "\. c", also works (C=FormFeed). However "\. 9" doesn't do a thing whereas you'd expect a tab there ("\.09" does that).

Comment: @Sjoerd Maybe time to write an answer and to tag as bug?

Comment: OK, something like the below?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Note that with versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 evaluation of `"\."` produces error message `Syntax::sntoct2: 2 hexadecimal digits are required after \. to construct an 8-bit character.` In version 10.4.1 this message is *defined* (evaluate `Syntax::sntoct2`) but isn't generated in this case...

Comment: With version 5.2 evaluation of `"foo bar \\. daz."` produces the expected result but with versions 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 I observe the line break after `d`.

Comment: I do not observe the cursor jump after *typing* `d` during typing `"\\. d` with versions 5.2, 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 on Windows 7 x64. But after evaluating `"\\. d"` I get additional empty line in the output with versions 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 (but not with version 5.2).

Comment: I **do observe** cursor jump after typing `d` during typing `"\\\. d` with versions 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 on Windows 7 x64  (but not with version 5.2). Evaluation of `"\\\. d"` triggers the `Syntax::sntoct2` message with versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 but not with version 10.4.1.

Comment: It is interesting that evaluation of `"\\\\. d"` produces the expected output (i.e. `\\. d`) with the all versions tested.

Comment: What is a bit surprising is that evaluation of `CellPrint@Cell@"\\. d"` in version 5.2 prints the cell `Cell["\n",  GeneratedCell->True,   CellAutoOverwrite->True]` but with versions 8.0.4 and 10.4.1 it prints ``Cell["\\. d", GeneratedCell->True, CellAutoOverwrite->True,  CellChangeTimes->{3.6753369642877436`*^9}]`` *which is displayed correctly*.

Comment: Also present in version 7. I guess probably introduced in 6.

Comment: That's a lot of bugs persisting through 11.0. :-/  How many have you found that have been fixed in 11?

Comment: Also would you check [my list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+%22persisting+through%22) when you have time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be related to the notation `"\.XX"` being used to enter characters in hexadecimal notation, as explained in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html).

For instance, entering `"\.09"` will get you the tab character, which in ASCII has the value 9. Similarly `"\.0d"` codes for the Carriage Return (CR) character.

What appears to be the bug is twofold:

1. `"\. d"` has the space acting as a zero, making it act like a CR and
2. in `"\\. d"` the first backslash is supposed to escape the second one (according to [this documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html), so that the string should consist of the literal characters "\", ".", " " and "d", but it doesn't work out that way.

Comment: This bug is also present in the 4-digit version as well. ``\:   d`` (with a colon and three spaces) also behaves the same way.